# Not passing a list of pointers correctly to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is the function prototype I have:

```
UINT8_t CTargetList::GetListOfTgts( CHAR_t Callsign[cTGT_MAX_CALLSIGN_CHAR],
   sTarget_t* ListOfTgtForCallsign[bNO_OF_TARGETS] );
```

Now when I create the structure to pass to this function

```
sTarget_t* TgtList[bNO_OF_TARGETS];
UINT8_t bRetTgts = list1.GetListOfTgts( "C1",&TgtList[bNO_OF_TARGETS]);
```

The structure is created correctly but when I trace the function, `ListOfTgtForCallsign` must be the array of pointers. Instead, `ListOfTgtForCallsign` only contains one pointer instead of `bNO_OF_TARGETS`. I want the list of pointers `TgtList` to be passed correctly as the `ListOfTgtForCallsign` parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in c++ arrays are [kinda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866275/not-passing-a-list-of-pointers-correctly-to-a-function/18866399#comment27842541_18866399) pointers.
You are passing a pointer to one after last element (bNO_OF_TARGETS) witch can also be used as array (that's why it passes compilation).
guess you need simply:

```
sTarget_t* TgtList[bNO_OF_TARGETS];
UINT8_t bRetTgts = list1.GetListOfTgts( "C1", TgtList);
```

Comment: the last element of the array is at index `bNO_OF_TARGETS-1`. what he is passing is the first element beyond the last

Comment: Thank you for the response but unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Logically your answer make sense and it should work. I can't understand why it didn't. Does the bNO_OF_TARGETS in the parameter of the function not have some influence regarding this matter?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to pass the array by a reference?

Comment: array is a pointer to its first element. so if you do it like in my snippet you are passing it as reference. @MariusBancila is right you probably need to initialize all elements to point to sTarget_t.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in some expressions but they are __not__ pointers.

Comment: @Blastfurnace : "beeing" is a fuzzy term. aren't they behaving exactly like static pointers? as far as i am concerned "int a[5];" is assembly-wise equivalent of "int const *a=new int[5];" and "a[3];" is "*(a+3);", or isn't it?

Comment: The convenience of array subscripting (address arithmetic) confuses the issue but arrays really aren't pointers. See: [Arrays are Pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers), [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c), [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

Comment: Simple example, given the two definitions of `a` in your comment, the result of `sizeof(a)` is different for `int a[5]` and `int *a`. Or given `int a[5], *b;` you do `b = a` but not `a = b`. They simply aren't the same type.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks a lot, this was interesting. fixed answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `TgtList` is an array of uninitialized pointers. Second, you are passing the address of the one beyond the last element of the array.

This is how you should call it.

```
UINT8_t bRetTgts = list1.GetListOfTgts( "C1", TgtList);
```

Answer (score 1):

in `list1.GetListOfTgts( "C1", &TgtList[bNO_OF_TARGETS] );` you pass address of an out-of-bounds element.

It should be just `list1.GetListOfTgts( "C1", TgtList );`

Also specifying the array sizes in the function prototype doesn't do what you probably want it to do.

Comment: Yes I changed it and it should fixed the problem but it doesn't. Could the array sizes in the function prototype cause this?