# Is name of a string a char pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
char str[100];
char *q;
```

what is the difference between `q` and `str`....aren't they both `char*`
Mind that I am talking about `str`, not `str[100]`

Comment: Try compiling `str++;` and you will see one important difference.

Comment: sizeof(str) =100bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char str[100];
```

`str` is the the name of an array object. It is not in any real sense a pointer.

But like any expression of array type, it is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to the address of (or equivalently, a pointer to) the array's first element. This implicit conversion yields a pointer *value*; there is no pointer *object*, so there's nothing that can be modified. (The resulting pointer value is of type `char*`, not `const char*` or `char *const`.)

The applicable exceptions here are when `str` is the operand of a unary `&` or `sizeof` operator.

```
char *q;
```

`q` is the name of a pointer object, and like nearly any non-`const` object it can be modified.

See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 1):

`q` is an uninitialized pointer, while `str` points to somewhere 100 bytes are allocated.

Also, you can change where `q` points to. But you cannot change the address of `str` later.

Comment: why we can change `q` but not `str`

Comment: Because that how it works.  `q` is a pointer that can be changed.  `str` is an array that cannot be changed in size, but its contents can.

Comment: `str` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

By convention the name of an array is a constant which its value is the address of first element of it.

In most cases when `str` is used in an expression or a statement it's implicitly converted to The address of the first element of the array. And one of the exceptions is with the `sizeof` operator. In this case (`sizeof(str)`), `str` is the array itself and it is not converted to an address and that's why `sizeof(str)` results `100`.

Comment: Then explain the result of `sizeof str`. And no, the pointer value to which `str` may be implicitly converted is not `const`.

Comment: At a minimum, it would be `char *const`, i.e., a constant pointer to non constant `char`. What you have is a non-constant pointer to a constant char.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm: No, it's just `char*`. The declaration of `str` does not create a pointer object, so no `const` is needed to avoid modifying any pointer object. Similarly, the value of `2+2` is of type `int`, not `const int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Is It clear now?

Comment: Clear, but incorrect. There is no `const`, and an array name is not *always* converted to a pointer value. Think about what your answer implies about the result of `sizeof str`.

Comment: @KeithThompson How is that?

Comment: That's still incorrect; see my previous comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Agreed, and I think you explained it perfectly in your answer. But at the very least, if you're going to think in terms of `const`s and pointers, then it is the pointer that is "constant", not the value that it points to. I understand there's no actual pointer here to be `const`, but `char *const` is a closer approximation than `const char*`.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm: `const` and "constant" are two distinct concepts, in spite of their similar names. `const` really means read-only, and it refers to *objects*. Given an array object, there is no pointer object for `const` to refer to. "Constant" refers to an expression that can be evaluated at compile time. Certainly `const char*` is incorrect, since you can modify the `char` elements. But `char *const` (const pointer to char) is still incorrect. The type of the expression, after the implicit conversion, is simply `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

Array vs. pointer questions already exist in great multitude on StackOverflow.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers), and [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/).

Answer (score 0):

In term of accessing the data in the string, yes, `str` can be thought of as a `char*`, or more accurately, a `char *const` because you cannot assign a different address to `str`.

Strictly speaking, they are different types, which is why you can't assign a new value to `str`. Think of it like the compiler: every variable is just a label for a particular address that it will allocate for you. `str`, represent an address of the start of a buffer made up of 100 `char`s, but  `q` is the address of an address, which in turn is the address of a `char`.

You can change the *value* of a variable, but you can't change (at run time) where a variable is placed (i.e., its address).

Comment: Surely you mean `char* const`?

Comment: why `str` is constant but `q` not

Comment: @learner: I've updated my answer with some more details. Let me know if that makes sense. Also, try drawing a picture of what the variables look like in memory to get a better idea.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm : but `q` is also the address of a character

Comment: @learner: The *value* of `q` is the address of a character, and that you can change. When you treat `str` like a pointer to a char, it's not the value of `str` that is being used to point to the `char`, it's the *address* of `str`, which you can't change.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm I think you got it wrong in your comment (but right in the answer): `const char*` and `char const*` mean the same, and are different from `char *const`

Comment: You have it wrong: `char const*` is the same as `const char*`, not `char* const`.

Comment: @rullof: No, the standard does not say that.

Comment: @TonyK: Ugh, sorry, you're right. I'll update my answer. Thanks

Comment: There is no `const` here.

Comment: @learner: I'm glad this was helpful to you, but you should also see Keith Thompson's answer. It's much more precise.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm :I have read it after his last edit

Comment: its very unfortunate that I can not accept two answers

Answer (score 0):

In that example str is of type char[100], whereas q is a pointer to a char. It could point to any single array element of type char, but not to an array of type char.

Comment: `q` cannot point to an array of `char`. It can point to an element of an array of `char`; you can then use pointer arithmetic to access other elements of the array.