# Error Accessing the content of the Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am doing a little bit practice of the pointers and I am facing this error? Anybody knows why is it there?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool expandarray(int **arr, int oldsize, int newsize)
{
    if(oldsize > newsize)
        return false;
    int *newarray = new int[newsize];
    for(int i = 0; i < newsize; i++)
    {
        newarray[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < oldsize; i++)
    {
        newarray[i] = *arr[i];
    }
    delete [](*arr);
    *arr = newarray;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int * array = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i+6;
        //cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    expandarray(&array,5,7);
    system("pause");
}
```

It is not getting the elements of the arr. The error occurs at `newarray[i] = *(arr[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing in the wrong order. What you have (implicitly) is `*(arr[i])` and what you want is `(*arr)[i];`.

This might be of interest to you: [Arrays are Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers)