# Intricacies of strcpy_s in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am having a difficult time obtaining the correct size of a string in order to satisfy strcpy_s.   For example if I specify

```
char buffer = {0};
char *str1 = (char*)&buffer;    
strcpy_s(str1,sizeof("This is a string\n"),"This is a string\n");
```

Then it will work as expected.   If however I declare the following:

```
char buffer = {0};
char *str1 = (char*)&buffer;
const char* string1 = "This is a string.....";
strcpy_s(str1, ?????,string1);
```

If I use anything other than a literal in place of ????? it will fail with a memory exception, for example if I use std:strlen(str1), etc.  Any size literal for ???? will work.   Of course using a fixed literal is not acceptable.

This is a major re-edit of the original question and I apologise to the people who have answered to date.   However none of the the answers below have worked.

Comment: The second argument should be the size of the destination, that is the size of str1. In other words, how much space is available.

Comment: [Learn the difference between arrays and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers).

Comment: Your first attempt is not correct, even if it “works” (at some point it will crash). It is not correct for you have allocated a buffer that can hold **one character, only** and you are copying more than one character. The correct call would be `strcpy_s(str1, sizeof(buffer),"This is a string\n");`. However, you will not get the expected result since the buffer is only 1 character long. To see something you should allocate a large enough buffer: `char buffer[128]`, for instance. This buffer will hold a 127 characters long string (plus terminating null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"This is a string"` is a character array. When you say `sizeof(Array)/sizeof(type)` it will give the size of the array
When you define the string as `const char*` then the sizeof(pointer) gives the size allocated for the pointer no the array size

```
const char* ptr = "This is a string\n";
std::cout<<sizeof("This is a string\n")<<std::endl; //==>18
std::cout<<sizeof(ptr)<<std::endl; //==>4
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the second parameter is **the size of the destination buffer, not the size of the source buffer**.

so the correct way is:

```
char str1[100];
strcpy_s(str1, sizeof str1, "Whatever string");
```

or

```
int n = 100;
char *str1 = new char[n];
strcpy_s(str1, n, "whatever string");
```

For an array (first example) `sizeof` returns the size of the array.

For a pointer (second example) `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer (which is not what you want)

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `string1` is of type `const char*`. `sizeof` will return the size of the *pointer*, rather than the length of the string literal you are pointing to.

The first example works because a string literal is a `const char[]`, and `sizeof` will correctly return the length of the string (but with the null terminating character as well). It's only coincidental that this works because `char` is 1 byte. Do not use `sizeof` to get string lengths.

To make your second example work, try using `std::strlen`.