# How to define a fixed sized array using new in C++

Tags: c++

How do you initialize the value of x using array new:

```
int (*x)[5] = ?
```

`new int[5]` doesn't work because it has a type of `int*`

Do you have to use a C-style cast as follows?

```
int (*x)[5] = (int( *)[5])(new int[5]);
```

Comment: Are you using an array instead of std:vector because of some constraint of your project?

Comment: do you mean how to create array of pointers dynamically ?

Comment: You understand `int (*x)[5];` declares a pointer to array of 5 `int`? It needs the address of a valid array of 5-ints, or can serve as the pointer to multiple arrays of 5 ints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing array decay when allocating memory on the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494479/preventing-array-decay-when-allocating-memory-on-the-heap)

Answer (score 5):

A fixed sized array in C++ would be [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

And, guessing from the pointer to array `int (*x)[5]` this might be either

```
std::array<int, 5> x;
```

or

```
std::array<int, 5> *x = new std::array<int, 5>;
```

Although the former is preferred, unless there's a real need to put the array on the heap.

---

If you want a variable number of fixed sized arrays, combine this with a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 5> > x;
```

Comment: It's funny. `std::array` is around for a decade now, and it is the first time I see it allocated with `new` :)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I haven't either.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
typedef int int5[5];

int main()
{
    int (*x)[5] = new int5[1];
    return 0;
}
```

There may be a way to do it without a typedef, but I didn't investigate too much.

UPDATE

Somewhat counter intuitively this is also correct

```
int (*x)[5] = new int[1][5];
```

And no you shouldn't use a cast, casts are rarely the right solution, especially for beginners.