# Assigning value to two dimensional array with the use of pointers C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a task which states: "your task is to fill the 10x10 matrix with values that will turn it into a multiplication table. You mustn't use brackets. You mustn't use indexing. Ergo, you must use pointers."

The output should be following: 
[10x10 multiplication table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN30C.png)

That's the solution that I end up with:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main(void) {
int matrix[10][11] = {};

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
            matrix[i-1][j-1]= i*j;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout.width(4);
        cout << matrix[i][j]; }

        cout << endl;
    } 
}
```

I tried to think of how can I use pointers instead of indexing, but I could find any information about how to use pointers with two dimensional arrays.

I just started learning C++ and it would be very kind if your help would be descriptive enough for me to understand and in the simplest form.

Thank you!

Comment: `matrix[i-1][j-1]` what element index would this would make if both `i` and `j` are `0`?

Comment: `You mustn't use brackets` this is a little ambiguous

Comment: Why you need 10x11 matrix if there are only 10 rows and 10 columns

Comment: A while back I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~eyudin/string_array_syntax.html) for an intro CS class that describes the relationship between the dereference and array index syntax. It also explains how to understand how to indentify "where you are" and what type you have while progressively dereferencing multi-dimensional arrays / multi-level pointers. See especially the section on Dereferencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main(void) {
int matrix[11][11] = {};

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            *(*(matrix + i - 1) + j - 1) = i * j;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout.width(4);
        cout << matrix[i][j]; }

        cout << endl;
    } 
}
```

`int[][]` can be used as `int**`

so matrix can be treated as an `int**`
and `*(matrix + i)` is the same thing as `matrix[i]`

Comment: "`int[][]` are equivalent to `int**`" No, it isn't.

Comment: they aren't equivalent in all manners but you can use a int[][] as an int**

Comment: @Tyker Consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers

Comment: Now you can safely allocate 10x10 array

Comment: @Tyker thank you, now I have a better image of how it works!

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding what your assignment is, is to understanding the layout of variables in the memory. Link: [Array declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)

> A declaration of the form `T a[N];`, declares `a` as an array object that consists of `N` contiguously allocated objects of type `T`.

A declaration: `int matrix[10][11]` means that there are 10 arrays of 11 int's each.

BUT because this is ALSO continuous, that means that this can also be interpreted as `10*11 = 110` continuous int's. `int matrix_1D[ 110 ]`;

So how to get at these elements?

Usually this is done taking the address of the first element: `&matrix[0][0]`.

The result:

```
const int n = 10;
const int m = 10;
int matrix[ n ][ m ];

int* matrix_ptr = &matrix[0][0];

for ( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
    for ( int j = 1; j <= m; ++j )
    {
        *matrix_ptr = i * j;
        ++matrix_ptr;
    }
```

By using the `++` operator the pointer will move to the next element.

For output a better choice is to use the [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for ( const auto& row : matrix )
{
    for ( const auto& num: row )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 4 ) << num;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the final solution I came up with:

```
    int matrix[10][10];

    // *(*(matrix + 0)+1); -----> matrix[0][1]
    // int** ----> int[][]

    for(int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
        for(int j = 1; j < 11; ++j)
            *(*(matrix+i-1)+j-1)=i*j;
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout.width(4);
        cout << matrix[i][j]; }

        cout << endl;}
```

Thank you, everyone!

Comment: in your first for loop you set the index to 0 and acces the element at i-1 so you are acessing the element at -1 wich is a mistake

Comment: After the edit looks like the "off by one" error is fixed :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: "Why numbering should start at zero?" prof.dr. Edsger W. Dijkstra.  http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html