# Array and pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am wondering how come the # number1 code not working 
as I am trying to use increment operator to display the next following element in the array.

But the # number2 code works , and it was the same code but in a function

```
//# number 1 code
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arrays[5]={2,4,6,8,10};

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        cout<<*arrays<<endl;
        arrays++;    //error: lvalue required as increment operand
    }
}


//# number 2 code
using namespace std;

void display(int *arr,int size){
    for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
        cout<<*arr<<endl;
        arr++;    //This time no error!!!
    }
}

int main(){
    int arrays[5]={2,4,6,8,10};

    display(arrays,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pointer value (the address of pointee) may be incremented. Although, the array decays to a pointer for nearly everything, it still is an array and (the address) may not be incremented. Assigning `arrays` to a corresponding pointer in `main()`, it would work as well. May be of interest: [SO: Arrays are Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960723/7478597).

Answer (score 3):

That's because you cannot change the address of an array.
In # number 1 code when you do array++, you are actually trying to operate directly on the variable which is storing the base address of the array.
What you can try instead is something like below:

```
int *p = array;
p++;
```

Whereas in the case when you are calling a function passing the array's base address # number 2, you are implicitly doing what has been shown in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem for beginners. **Arrays are not pointers!**. Arrays are implicitly converted to pointers. That is where the confusion lies. Consider this:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
std::cout << *array << '\n';
```

What do you think is happening when we do `*array`. Does it really make sense to *dereference an array*? The array is being implicitly converted to a `int *` and then dereferenced. What about this:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
array++;
std::cout << *array << '\n';
```

This doesn't compile (as you found out for yourself). In this statement `array++`, the `array` is not implicitly converted to a pointer.

Arrays are converted to pointers when you pass them to functions that accept pointers. That makes it possible to do this:

```
int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
display(array, 3);
```

An array is a sequence of objects stored on the stack. You access this sequence of objects as a pointer to the first object. Both arrays and pointers can be subscripted. They share many similarities but are fundamentally different.

To make your first example compile, subscript the array with `x`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  std::cout << arrays[x] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
int *arr = arrays;
arr++;
```

in code #1. It will work. This is because you need first to create a pointer to the base of the array which you can increment as in the second code, you have the pointer in the form of the passed argument to the function.