# How can a char variable parameter take in a string?

Tags: c++, parameters

Assume a function with one parameter of `const char*` type. When I use a string when calling that function, nothing goes wrong! I would expect that you could only input characters included in the ASCII, for example `c` or dec `68`, but it seem otherwise. Take a look at the code below...

```cpp
void InitFunction(const char* initString)
{
  std::cout << initString;
}

int main()
{
  InitFunction("Hello!");
}
```

When you run the code, no problem, warnings, or errors appear. I did some more testing on this as you can see from the following...

```cpp
void InitFunction(char initString)
{
  std::cout << initString;
}

int main()
{
  InitFunction("Hello!");    // compiler error on this line
}
```

This compiles with an error since `Hello!` cannot be converted into `char`. I tried another test, but instead used `const char` as the function parameter type. The code still compiles with an error. But when I add `*` to the function parameter type, then everything compiles fine! It appears to me that the `const` is also necessary.

To my understanding of pointers, the function is asking for a pointer, and the pointer is identified as being a character. But this raises three problems for me.

- First, `Hello!` is not in the form of a pointer. I would expect at least to have to use the reference operator (`&`).
- Second, `Hello!` is not a `char` type.
- And third, why do we need to include the `const`?

Am I missing something here? Do pointers and characters work in ways that I don't know?

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: How do you know? Sams Teach Yourself. It's actually really easy to understand, but I'm just stuck on this part.

Comment: What do you mean "how do I know"? [Here are the books we recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the function is asking for a pointer

Correct.

> and the pointer is identified as being a character

No, a pointer is a not a character. A pointer is a pointer. This pointer points to one or more characters, i.e. an array of characters. And that's exactly what your string literal is.

> First, Hello! is not in the form of a pointer.

Yes, it is. The string literal `"Hello!"` has type `const char[7]` and this decays to a pointer.

> I would expect at lest to have to use the reference operator (&).

That's the address-of operator. You don't always need it to get a pointer. Example: `this`.

> Second, Hello! is not a char type.

No, but each constituent character is.

> And third, why do we need to include the const?

Because the string literal `"Hello!"` has type `const char[7]`. Dropping the `const` would violate `const`-correctness and is therefore not permitted.

> This throws an error since Hello! cannot be converted into char.

That's right. A `char` is one byte. The string `"Hello!"` is not one byte. It is a string.

---

A C-string is typically/conventionally/usually provided in `const char*` form.

You should read the chapter in your book about this subject as it's a fundamental of the language. It has nothing to do with ASCII (text encodings are irrelevant to storing a sequence of bytes).

Comment: Oh okay. I understand. So "Hello" would be treated as a string, but it can also work as an array of characters?

Comment: @FuzzySquid What's the difference between the two? A string _is_ an array of characters. Always has been.

Comment: Oh okay. One last thing though, what do you mean `const char[7]` "decays" to a pointer?

Comment: It means you can pass an array of `T`s to a function that is looking for a pointer-to-`T`*s. There is a built-in compatibility rule. If you use a recommended book it will explain this. (Watch out: some bad books incorrectly claim that "arrays are pointers", because their authors have been confused by this compatibility rule.)

Answer (score 2):

`"Hello!"` is a `const char` array of characters. Arrays are treated like a pointer, they decay to a pointer when used in a function call as an argument. The C++ standard specifies this in order to be compatible with the way that the C language standard specifies arrays are to be treated.

By the way this array decay to a pointer happens with other cases where an array is being used where a pointer or the address operator could be used such as an assignment statement. See also [Arrays are Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers)

So `"Hello!"` will be put into the argument list of `InitFunction()` as a pointer which points to where the compiler has stored the array of characters with the terminating zero character added. When the compiler generates the code for the function call, the pointer to the array of characters used as an argument to the function is `const char *`, a pointer to a `char` which is `const` and should not be changed.

When you have the function prototype as `InitFunction(const char *)`, the compiler is fine with a function call such as `InitFunction("Hello!");`. What you are doing is providing a `const char *` that points to `"Hello!"`.

However if you remove the `const` then since `"Hello!"` is a `const` the compiler complains. The compiler complains because a `const` variable is being used in a function call whose argument list is non-const indicating that the function may change what the pointer is pointing to. Since "Hello!" is not supposed to be changed, since it is `const`, the compiler issues an error.

If you remove the asterisk, change `const char *` to `const char`, then since `"Hello!"` is a `char` array which the compiler then decays into a pointer to the first element of the array, the compiler complains as you are trying to use a pointer for an argument that is not a pointer. In this alternative the problem is the actual data type, `char` versus `char *` is the problem.

The following lines of code would also be acceptable:

```
const char *p = "Hello!";  // create a pointer to an series of characters
char x1[] = "Hello!";      // create an array of char and initialize it.
char *p2 = x1;             // create a pointer to char array and initialize it.
char *p3 = x1 + 2;         // create a pointer to char array and initialize it with address of x1[2].

InitFunction (p);    // p is a const char *
InitFunction (x1);   // x1 decays to a char *
InitFunction (p2);   // p2 is a char *
InitFunction (p3);   // p3 is a char *

InitFunction (x1 + 3);  // called with address of x1[3].
```

Note also C++ has an actual character string type, `string`, that results in a dynamic character text string whose underlying physical memory layout normally includes a pointer to an array of characters. The C style array of characters that is labeled a string is not the same thing as the C++ `string` type.

Comment: Well done, just a little fuzzy on the array-pointer conversion thing. While "*[arrays] decay to a pointer when used in a function call as an argument*" is perfectly true, it is not the whole truth. Arrays are converted to a pointer *on access* subject to the four exceptions contained in [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). That will help prevent the lingering question of "Where else do arrays decay to a pointer?"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you for your comment with the reference to the C standard. It motivated me to look further for what amounts to a similar question within Stackoverflow that contains a number of answers with quite a bit of elaboration.

Comment: Yes, I always try and re-emphasize the issues I can remember having the "Now how the heck does that really work?" questions about. (and there are still a lot of them by the way...)