# How could value of array b[] is filled with another array a[] value from another function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters

I found this code in internet.And i am confused from 1 hour.
What i found weird is that array b[] is inside met2() function with local scope. And there is another array a[] which is inside met1() function with it's local scope . But How could value of a[] is transferred to b[] array. 
And Most importantly, both function are not returning any values. 
This is so confusing. Please Help me out here. I searched online but nobody had asked such questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    met2();
    return 0;
}
void met1(int a[1])
{
    a[0]=199;
}
void met2()
{
    int b[1];
    met1(b);
    printf("%d",b[0]);
}
```

Comment: array name decays to pointer and internally `met1` is declared as `void met1(int *a)`;

Comment: Dou you know, what a pointer is?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX 
i am afraid, i lack knowledge about pointer sir.
is this pointer problem?

Comment: @kiranBiradar i don't really get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays are Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers)

Comment: @ArjunBhat Please go through the above link.

Comment: @ArjunBhat I don't understand what you mean with "pointer problem". This is a c program which uses pointers to transfer array-values, nothing more

Comment: @kiranBiradar Dhanyabaad Guru

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

When you call

```
met1(b);
```

the *expression* `b` is converted from type "1-element array of `int`" to type “pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the address of `b[0]`.

In the function prototype

```
void met1(int a[1])
```

the parameter declaration `int a[1]` is "adjusted" to `int *a` - it’s actually being declared as a pointer (which is handy, since that’s what the function actually receives).

So when`met2` calls `met1`, it’s passing the address of the first element of `b`.  The `[]` operator can be used on pointers as well as arrays (it’s actually defined in terms of pointer arithmetic - `a[i]` is interpreted as `*(a + i)`).

So writing `a[0] = 199;` in `met1` is equivalent to writing `b[0] = 199;` in `met2`.

Comment: You worked very hard to make me understand it, in very easy way. 
i am very grateful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to understand that whenever we declare an array as parameter of a function, it gets adjusted to a pointer to its first element. C17 6.7.6.3 emphasis mine:

> **A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to** "qualified **pointer to type**", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.

This means that `void met1(int a[1])` and `void met1(int* a)` are 100% equivalent. The former gets silently translated to the latter by the compiler.

This is quite confusing because `int a[1]` looks like an array declaration and one might easily get idea the idea that the array is passed by value. But passing arrays by value isn't possible in C.

In your case, the local array `b` gets passed to `met1` as a pointer to its first element. With `a[0] = ...` that pointed-at element is changed.

Comment: Thank you sir..
That is very helpful for me.
I have learned great lessons from you guys. 
I will do more reaching out, if i stuck on some problems.