# Array pointer c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello i would like to find out how its doing. I have code like that:

```
int tab[] = {1,2,3};
int* p;
p = tab; 

cout <<p<<endl; //  cout adress here 
cout <<p[0]<<endl; //  cout first element of the array
```

How its doing  that `p` is storing address of first element  but `p[0]` is already storing first element?
its working like `p[0] = *p` ? and `p[1]` is working like `p[1] = *(p+1)`?
I know how to use it but I'm little confused because i don't really understand it

Comment: Well, you answered it already yourself. p is a pointer. p[0] is a *(p+0). * is used to get the value from the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How its doing that `p` is storing address of first element

The data type `int tab[]` is the same as `int*`, so does the type of `p`.
So both these variables point to the same memory location, and that will be the start of the array.

> but `p[0]` is already storing first element?

Variable `tab` contains a pointer to the first element of `tab[0]`, so assigning the same value to another variable will have an equivalent effect.

> its working like `p[0] = *p ?` and `p[1]` is working like `p[1] = *(p+1)`?

Yes, `*(p+i)` is same as `p[i]`.

If you need a detailed explanation please check [this link](https://www.studytonight.com/c/pointers-with-array.php#:%7E:text=Pointer%20and%20Arrays%20in%20C,also%20allocated%20by%20the%20compiler.)

Comment: *The data type `int tab[]` is the same as `int*`*. Not correct. [Arrays and pointers are very different.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960723/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301 In this context it is a pointer to int by the same article you mentioned. "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’

Answer (score 2):

> How its doing that p is storing address of first element

`p` is a pointer. A pointer stores an address.

> but p[0] is already storing first element?

`p[0]` is an an element of the array. It stores an integer.

It is possible for a program to store both of these at the same time.

> its working like p[0] = *p ? and p[1] is working like p[1] = *(p+1)?

Correct. This is how the subscript operator works on pointer and integer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer p points to the first variable of an array and as the array has a contiguous allocation of memory, so on *(p+1) it starts pointing to the second variable of the array.
You can understand this by further example.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    // Pointer to an integer 
    int *p;  
      
    // Pointer to an array of 5 integers 
    int (*ptr)[5];  
    int arr[5]; 
      
    // Points to 0th element of the arr. 
    p = arr; 
      
    // Points to the whole array arr. 
    ptr = &arr;  
      
    cout << "p =" << p <<", ptr = "<< ptr<< endl; 
    p++;  
    ptr++; 
    cout << "p =" << p <<", ptr = "<< ptr<< endl; 
      
    return 0; 
}
```