# Length of int array

Tags: arrays, c

```
void test(int* x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < y; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            x[j] = i;
            ++j;
        }
    }
}

int maxRange = 10;
int *a;
test(a, maxRange);
// a = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }
```

How can I find length of `a`?

The length is `6`.

I tried `sizeof(a)` and `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't, you need to pass it as argument.

Comment: Loop does  not attempt `x[5] = 10`.  There are no _arrays_ in this code.

Comment: You need to assign something to `a`, at which point you'll know how long it is.  You just have to keep track.  In the posted code, `a` has never been set, so your function is corrupting memory (it's a bug).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the major problems working with arrays in C: no way to know the length of it, but there are ways to work around this:

- Either you keep track of the amount of entries you put in the array (as already proposed by Sourav).
- Either you start by putting default values into your array (like `-1`). If ever you need to know the length of the array, you just look for the index of the first `-1` and if there isn't one, it means that your array has reached full length.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the length of the allocated memory to a pointer, from a pointer using `sizeof` operator. You need to keep track it yourself, and pass it around to any function call which may need it.

Related reading: [Arrays are Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3959705/2173917)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find length of `a`?

`a` is a *pointer*, not an *array*.  It has not been assigned a value.  `a` has a length in that a pointer take up so many bytes like 4 or 8, but `a` does not point to any length of memory for data, yet.

Instead, allocate memory:

```
int n = (maxRange + 1)/2;  // Number of `int` used by test().
a = calloc(n, sizeof *a);  // Allocate zero'd memory.
if (a) {
  test(a, maxRange);
  for (int i = 0; i < n, i++) printf(" %d", a[i]);
  free(a);
}
```

---

If code hopes to print 0 2 4 6 8 10, change allocation and `test()` loop condition

```
// int n = (maxRange + 1)/2;
int n = (maxRange + 2)/2;

// for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < y; ++i) {
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= y; ++i) {
```