# standard conversions: Array-to-pointer conversion

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the point from ISO *:Standard Conversions:Array-to-pointer conversion: $4.2.1*

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array
>   of N T” or “array of unknown bound of
>   T”     can be converted to an rvalue
>   of type “pointer to T.” The result is
>   a pointer     to the first element of
>   the array.

Can any one explain this, if possible with an example program.

I seen these links already, but i am unable to understand:

[Array and Rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656726/array-and-rvalue)

[I think I may have come up with an example of rvalue of array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058151/i-think-i-may-have-come-up-with-an-example-of-rvalue-of-array-type)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In both C and C++, an array can be used as if it were a pointer to its first element.  Effectively, given an array named `x`, you can replace most uses of `&x[0]` with just `x`.

This is how subscripting is able to be used with array objects:

```
int x[5];
x[2];     // this is the same as (&x[0])[2]
```

This is also how an array can be passed to a function that has a parameter of pointer type:

```
void f(int* p);

int x[5];
f(x);     // this is the same as f(&x[0])
```

There are several contexts in which the array-to-pointer conversion does not take place.  Examples include when an array is the operand of `sizeof` or the unary-`&` (the address-of operator), when a string literal is used to initialize an array, and when an array is bound to a reference to an array.

Comment: x[2] is the same as *(&x[0] + 2); did you mean x + 2 is the same as &x[0] + 2?  There's a problem defining subscripting in terms of &x[0] (which is also subscripting).

Comment: Another such context is when the array is bound to a reference to array. Cheers,

Comment: @Fred:  Ugh, that was really bad; thanks for pointing it out.  I actually meant `(&x[0])[2]`, since I was attempting to show equivalence between `x` and `&x[0]`.  Your example would work too, though.

Comment: @Alf:  Thanks for reminding me about the reference-to-array issue.  There's also the case when a string literal (which is an array) is used as an initializer.  Have we missed any other cases or is that all of them?

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[6];
int *b = a;
```

Pointer b points to the a[0], i.e. contains the address of the element a[0].

Answer (score 1):

This means, that you can have the following situation:

```
int arr[100];
arr[ 0 ] = arr[ 1 ] = 666;
// ..
```

You can use `arr` as pointer to `int`, which points to the first element of the array, for example:

```
*arr = 123;
```

and then the array will be: `arr = { 123, 666, ... }`

Also, you could pass the array to a function, that takes int*:

```
void f( int* a ) { /* ... */ }
```

and call it:

```
f( arr );
```

It's absolutely the same as calling it like this:

```
f( &arr[ 0 ] );
```

That is what `The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.` means.

---

Another way, you could use the address of the first element is:

```
*( &arr[ 0 ] + 1 ) = 222;
```

this will make the second element in the array with value `222`; It's the same as

```
arr[1] = 222;
```

and

```
*( arr + 1 ) = 222;
```

Comment: Okay, agree, edited. Removed the part with "name of the array", my bad.

Answer (score 0):

One example of this is that any array variable will automatically degenerate into a pointer to it's first element when passed to a function which takes a pointer of the array's type.

Take a look at this section from the C-Faq on [Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).  This is equally applicable in C++.

```
void foo(int *a) {
    a[0] = 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int b[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    foo(b);

    printf("b[0] == %d\n", b[0]);
}
```