# Address of a pointer to an array on the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to store an array of characters on the heap.

The following code works

```
char *array[3];
*array = new char;
```

And also the following

```
char *array[3];
array[0] = new char;
```

But not the following

```
char *array[3];
array = new char;
```

I viewed the contents of `*array`, `array[0]` and `array`. The first and second do not contain valid pointer addresses after assigning using `new` but the third one does. 
So what makes the third one not work? How do the other two work while they just seem to store some unknown symbols (such as $,%,-) rather than the actual address of the pointer?

Comment: Please consider one of our friendly `std::string` classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it will help to elaborate what a `char *array[3]` is. This is an array of three pointers, which point to characters. That is, `array[0]`, `array[1]`, and `array[2]` are each pointers to a character. So, `*array` and `array[0]` are fine places (and in fact the same place) to store a pointer to a character, but `array` isn't even a pointer, it is an array, so trying to store a pointer there doesn't make sense.

If you want to store characters in the heap (using a c-style array of characters), you should just do `char *array;` and then initialize it as `array = new char[3];`

However, since you are using C++, it is recommended you either use `std::string` if you are trying to store a string, or `std::vector` if you want a list of single characters.

Comment: Why do they return some weird symbols and not an address even though I stored an address in them?

Comment: @MohammadSanei How did you view them?

Comment: I can't type it using my keyboard but it was a string of three weird characters.

Comment: @MohammadSanei I mean, what did you do to look at them? `printf`? `gdb`?

Comment: Well, you were probably seeing junk values. When you call `new char`, it initializes memory, but doesn't set it to 0, so you were probably just seeing what was in there before. Also, `std::cout` tries to figure out what kind of value you are trying to print out, so when you do `std::cout << array[0]` it thinks you are trying to print out a c-style string (a `char*`) and thus prints it as a string, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question. How is `*array` a pointer? Why does it seem to me like a dereferenced value of a pointer?

Comment: @MohammadSanei See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223617/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion (it answers your question better than I could in a comment)

Comment: Now I get it! `*array` is the same as `array[0]`, and to give an array an address you should give the first element an address. Thanks for your help.