# Pointer multidimensional array to multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

In C++, is there a way to convert a `float**` to a `float[][]` type? I also would like to know how to convert it the other way around too.

Comment: How would you use this? There are some small differences, like defining a var as an array would have its memory stored contiguously but not in the case of `**`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert anything. Just dereference it by `[][]`:

```
float **a;

// allocate memory //

a[0][0] = 1;
```

Be careful to don't touch out-of-bound items which didn't allocate.

Answer (score 0):

you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223617/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion) to see some more examples, but basically as M M said, you don't need to convert and you can always do:

```
int x[10];
int *y = x;
```

same with 2 dimensional arrays