# Passing an array to function without changing its value?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to do something with array A in function B. In function B, some value of A is changed. I know that because A is a pointer so its values will be changed after B is executed. So that I have to use C which is a copy of A to make sure that A aren't changed after B is executed.

I am wonder that is there any other way that I don't have to use the array C?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it:

1. If you are using C++11, use `std::array`.
2. Use `std::vector<int>` to pass array. You can modify local copy and argument array won't change.
3. If you want not to modify value, pass it as const * or const reference to array. For ex `const int *arr` or `const int (&arr)[10]`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to pass an array by value in C++.

You either have to manually make a copy of it and "pass" that, or replace the array with a container that wraps an array such as `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parameter `const` if you don't want to change its values:

```
void func( const int * intArray, size_t size) {...}
```

Comment: Would you not pass it as a const ref though?  If all you're doing is reading from the array etc?

Comment: Actually, ignore me, just spotted it.  Sorry about that.  Totally forgot you have an array of ints like that the same way you can do char*....sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

or you can write something like this:

```
void func (const int array[10])
{
   // you can work with you data here withot changing an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a pointer to an array and you want to make sure that the array content is not modified inside the function, you can use `const`:

```
void DoSomething(const int * data, size_t size)
```

In C++, you may want to consider a *container class* like `std::vector`, and you can pass it using a *reference to `const`* (to avoid useless and potentially expensive deep-copies of vector):

```
void DoSomethingCppStyle(const std::vector<int>& data)
```

Note that in this case there is no need to pass a size parameter separately, since `std::vector` knows its own size (returned by `std::vector::size()`).