# C++ Pass a reference to an array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Given to functions void main() and void hello(byte* a[4]). Main function has an array of four bytes. The array's reference needs to be passed to the function hello for manipulation. I would expect the right syntax to be:

```
void hello(byte* a[4]){
 // Manipulate array
 a[0] = a[0]+1;
}

void main(){
 byte stuff[4] = {0,0,0,0};
 hello(&stuff);
 // hopefully stuff is now equal {1,0,0,0}
}
```

Alternatively I see others using this form of decaration:

```
void hello(byte (&a)[4])
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Use `std::array<byte,4>&` instead.

Comment: With `hello(&stuff)` you pass a pointer to `hello`, beside that you should use `std::array`, `std::vector` or any other std container instead of `byte stuff[4]`

Comment: What is the benefit or motivation of using std::vector or std::array?

Comment: If anything, raw arrays have the nasty tendency to decay to pointers to their first element using std::array avoids that. Its also clearer (imo) when passing an std::array to a function if its by value, pointer or reference compared to raw arrays. Theres more reasons but those two are enough for me to prefer std::array to raw arrays pretty much all the time.

Comment: The benefit of using std containers is that  they will take care about the container related memory mamangment. That is is easier to read how the container is passed around in your code, and what kind of data is stored. In addition you benefit of all the methods and utility functions that are provided by the std library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many different options here depending on what you want to do here.

If you have a raw array of `byte` objects, you can pass it into a function like this:

```
void hello(byte arr[]) {
   // Do something with arr
}

int main() {
   byte arr[4];
   hello(arr);
}
```

The mechanism by which the array is passed into the function (a pointer to the first element of the array is passed to the function) functions similarly to pass-by-reference: any changes you make to `arr` in `hello` will stick in `main` even though you didn't explicitly pass in a reference to it. However, the `hello` function won't check whether the array has size four or not - it'll take in as input an array of *any* number of bytes.

You can also write

```
void hello(byte (&arr)[4]) {
   // ...
}

int main() {
    byte arr[4];
    hello(arr);
}
```

The syntax `byte (&arr)[4]` means "a reference to an array of four bytes." This explicitly passes the array by reference into `hello`, and it will check the size of the array to make sure it's correct. However, this is very unusual syntax and rarely seen in practice.

But perhaps the best idea is to not use raw arrays and to use `std::array` instead:

```
void hello(std::array<byte, 4>& arr) {
    // Do something with arr
}

int main() {
    std::array<byte, 4> arr;
    hello(arr);
}
```

Now, there's no weirdnesses about strange parentheses in the syntax for arrays of bytes and there's no worries about size checking. Everything is handled properly because `std::array` is an object type that has all the advantages of regular object types. I'd recommend going with this last approach above all the other ones.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are already passed by pointer.

So this:

```
int a(int array[]) {
}
```

Is the same as doing this:

```
int a(int * array) {
}
```

Doing this:

```
void hello(byte (&a)[4])
```

only allows arrays with a length of 4 to be passed in.

Comment: That's not what "pass by reference" means.

Comment: Careful - "pass by reference" has a specific meaning. If you pass an array into a function, you're actually passing a pointer to the first element of the array - by value - into the function.

Answer (score 2):

`byte* a[4]` is an array of four pointers to `byte`, except in a parameter list.
In a parameter list, it is a pointer to a pointer to a `byte` – i.e. it is equivalent to `byte**`.

`byte (*a)[4]` is a pointer to a four-element array.

`byte (&a)[4]` is a reference to a four-element array.

In your case, `&stuff` is a pointer to a four-element array, so your parameter should be `byte (*a)[4]`.