# How do I modify a vector in a function? C++

Tags: c++, function, vector

So I have a vector that I want to modify, and a function that should do so. But when I output the values of the vector after calling the function, nothing has changed.

Here is my vector:

```
vector<char> board = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
```

And here is my function:

```
void take_turn(vector<char> board) {
      int input;
      cin >> input;
      board[input] = 'x';
    }
```

Let's say the input is 1. Here is what I was expecting:

```
  , x,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
```

Here is what I get:

```
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
```

Comment: Take it by reference: `void take_turn(vector<char>& board)` or else you'll only modify the local copy inside the function.

Comment: By passing it by reference. [Does C++ pass objects by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215409/does-c-pass-objects-by-value-or-reference)