# struct member undefined behavior

Tags: c++, struct

I wrote a battle sim for a game i have in mind an didn't work. After maaany strugles i isolated the problem in this simple program. I have a struct with 2 members a variable and a member functio witch is to modify the variable in a similar struct by incrementing with 1. Program don't work. Variable in struct b remains the same even thou i modified it in "modify" member function. Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    int x{};

    void modify(test op)
    {
        op.x = op.x + 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test a{};
    a.x = 1;
    test b{};
    b.x = 2;
    a.modify(b);
    std::cout << b.x << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

when i run it i get 2, i should get 3

i expected member function modify to actually modify b.x

Comment: `void modify(test op)` you pass by value, so the function operates on a copy - you probably want `void modify(test& op)`

Comment: `void modify(test &op)` to pass by reference. Good job on isolating a minimal example!

Comment: [Does C++ pass objects by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215409/does-c-pass-objects-by-value-or-reference) and [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: [Arguments are passed by value, unless the function signature specifies otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21215444/12002570) as explained in answer of the first [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215409/does-c-pass-objects-by-value-or-reference). So for passing by reference you have to change the parameter to `test& op`. I would also recommend a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: fwiw there is no undefined behavior in your code. Its all totally fine valid c++, and behavior is as it should be

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" does not mean "surprising".

Comment: More informatively, "undefined behaviour" has a very specific meaning in C++; it means that the program isn't valid and that anything can happen. It is similar to how division by zero is undefined in maths, but you can still get a result (and even a "reasonable" one) if you happen to do it anyway.

Comment: Design tip: `modify` is a member function of `test`. It has an implicit argument whose type is `test`. That is, it could be simply `void test() { x = x + 1; }`, and you could call it with `a.modify();`.