# confusion on myClass ** p1 and myClass *p2[5]

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
class myClass{
     public:
      myClass(){
        cout<<"constructor called..."<<endl; }
};

int main(){
   myClass ** p1;
   myClass *p2[5];

   *(p2+4) = new myClass;
   *p1 = new myClass;  // "constructor called..." printed, but segmentation fault

   cout<<typeid(p1).name()<<endl; 
   // "PP7myClass" printed, after commenting out *p1 = new myClass;
   // what is PP7?
   cout<<typeid(2).name()<<endl; 
   // "A5_P7myClass" printed, after commenting out *p1 = new myClass; 
   //  what is A5_P7?

   if(typeid(p1)==typeid(p2)) cout<<"==="<<endl; 
   if(typeid(p1)==typeid(*p2)) cout<<"&&&"<<endl;
   // I expected at least one of the above cout 
   // two lines should be printed, but nothing printed actually, why?


   return 0;
   }
```

1. why there is segmentation fault after calling the constructor for `p1`?
2. If the line `*p1 = new myClass;` is commented out, "PP7myClass" and "A5_P7myClass" printed, what are "PP7" and "A5_P7"?
3. If I define a function `void func(myClass a, myClass b){}` and then do `func(p1, p2);`, the compiler will complain that can not convert `myClass **` to `myClass` for two arguments, so that means `p1` and `p2` are both of type `myClass **`, but why for the two lines above `return 0;`, nothing is printed?

Comment: `*p1` is an uninitialised pointer, you are trashing random memory by writing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `p1` itself doesn't actually point at something. So `*p1` dereferences uninitialized memory
2. They are name-mangled names of the types, as constructed by the compiler. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling
3. I don't see a `pc` variable or type defined/declared in your code. **EDIT** Because the prototype of `f()` calls for parameters of type `myClass` to be passed. `p2` is of type `myClass**` too; it is the name of an array of pointers to `myClass` and degenerates to type `myClass**`, see [standard conversions: Array-to-pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223617/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion)

Comment: 3, my bad, just changed.

Comment: 1. If I do `myClass * p1; p1 = new myClass;`, this works fine.    3. I understand the degeneration of array to pointer, but didn't realize that this happens before the array is passed to inside the function body.

Answer (score 2):

> why there is segmentation fault after calling the constructor for p1?

```
myClass ** p1;
```

says "gimme space for a pointer to a pointer"; not "gimme space at the point that this unitialized pointer points to, too".

>   2.

they are typeids.

> 3.

You don't initialize `pc` or `p` to be something: I wonder why your compiler doesn't stop you from doing this, but it seems `pc` has neither type of `p` nor of `*p`.

EDIT:

after your edit: The typeids of a pointer and an array aren't the same.

Comment: 2. What do you mean by "they are typeids"?

Comment: "PP7" and "A5_P7" are typeids.