# Access violation writing Location error during string assignment

Tags: c++, pointers

I am getting "Access violation" error but unable to identify the root cause for it . I am new to c++ and preparing for C++ coding contest as a beginner. Please help me to get the root cause for it. Please find the attached screenshot.

Thanks in advance .

Here is my code in a single .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(char *str) {
    char * end = str;
    char tmp;
    if (str) {
        while (*end) {
            ++end;
        }
        --end;
        while (str < end) {
            tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end; //Getting exception here
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    char *str="Test";
    cout << "Before change"<<str;     // prints Hello World!
    reverse(str);
    cout << "After change"<<str; // prints I'm a C++ program
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You can't write to string literals, `char *str="Test";` is the root cause and isn't valid C++, I'm surprised your compiler isn't complaining it should be `char const* str ="Test";`.

Comment: Actually char* str="Test" is allowed in c++. String literal are converted to const char* type. But the value pointed by str can not be changed because it is a constant.

Comment: @bkVnet It's been deprecated since C++03, and it's invalid as of C++11.

Comment: @user657267 You are right but shouldn't it be const char* str="Test" rather than char const* str="Test"( as in your first comment) because the second one will make the pointer constant and not the value it is pointing to.

Comment: @bkVnet There is no difference between `char const*` and `const char*`, they are the same type. You're thinking of `char* const`.

Comment: @bkVnet Thanks for your reply . One more clarification . Lets say i initialized it as a string array. So when i pass the same to reverse function it should throw exception as it accepts char *str which again going to be modified later inside the function

Comment: @vivek if you do it like the given answer char str[]="test", then what you are passing is not a const char* but char* which should work fine.

Comment: @user657267 Wow, never paid attention to that detail, thanks!!

Comment: @bkVnet Thanks mate . You made my day !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), because you are trying to edit the read-only memory where the literal string "Test" is stored (since string literals are `const char*` in c++).

In order to make your code run, you can store the literal string in a char array so the first line in `main()` will look like this:

```
char str[] = "Test";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .
One more clarification . 
Lets say i initialized it as a string array. So when i pass the same to reverse function it should throw exception as it accepts char *str which again going to be modified later inside the function.

Comment: do you mean a `char []` by *string array*?

Comment: Yes . like this .
char str[] = "Test";

Comment: then you don't have to change your function's prototype as conversion from array to pointer is done automatically for you, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223617/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion)

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer, the only thing you need to change in order to make the program run is the line `char *str="Test";`

Comment: Thanks mate . Now i got the whole thing!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type of string constants by default in C++ is const char *.

In the following line, you assign a non-const char * to a const char *.

```
char *str="Test";
```

Thus, when you pass this variable to the reverse function, you are attempting to write to read-only memory. This violates the rules of C++, and leads to unexpected behaviour.

Define your string like this instead to solve the problem:

```
char str[] = "Test";
```

This gives you the ability to modify the string, as it isn't a const anymore.

Comment: "you assign a non-const char * to a const char *."?!