# Assigning a string to a pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I just wanted to ask this:

In this piece of code I create a string and a pointer, what is the correct way to assign this string to the pointer?

```
char str[10] = "hello";
char* ptr
```

Does it work with `ptr = str`?
If not, why?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [standard conversions: Array-to-pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223617/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion)

Comment: Are you asking how to make the pointer point to the string? If so, which of the two strings are you talking about? (The string constant, "hello", or the character array `str` that contains the string "hello"?) Given that you didn't make `ptr` a pointer to `const char *`, I would assume the array. Is that correct?

Comment: You *cannot* assign a string to a pointer.  A string is a null-terminated array of characters.  You *can* assign the address of the first character to a pointer.  If you write `ptr = str`, then `ptr` will point to the first char of `str` (the 'h' that has been copied and assigned at runtime, not the `h` that is in the string constant).

Answer (score 4):

> What is the correct way to assign this string to the pointer?

None. You cannot assign a string to a pointer. You only can assign the pointer by the address of the first element of the array `str`, which was initialized by the string `"hello"`. It's a subtle but important difference.

> Does it work with `ptr = str`?

Yes, but it doesn't assign the string to the pointer. `str` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array of `char` `str`. After that, `ptr` is pointing to the array `str` which contains the string `"hello"`.

---

If you don't want to modify the string, You could simplify the code by initializing the pointer to point to a string literal, which is stored in read-only memory instead of an modifiable array of `char`:

```
const char* ptr = "hello";
```