# Put a word from a text file into an array

Tags: c++, input, fstream

im about to code a small application for myself. I have a code prepared.
It looks something like this.

```
ifstream file("input.txt");

if (file.is_open())
{
    string myArray[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        file >> myArray[i];
    }

    cout << myArray;
}
```

Can somebody say how to get the words from the input.txt into an array?
(Content of my txt file: "Bla Bla Bla") but the array just contains random numbers..

Kind regards

Comment: `cout << myArray;` won't work. You'll need to iterate through the items in the array and output them one by one, similar to how you input them from the file.

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
std::cout << myArray;
```

[array to pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223617/standard-conversions-array-to-pointer-conversion) takes place, and you print the address of your `myArray` first element. If you want to print 5 elements of your `std::string` array, just iterate over them like before when reading the file:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

also range loop will work here:

```
    for (const auto& str : myArray)
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
```