# Why is a hard-coded string constant an lvalue?

Tags: c++, string-literals, lvalue, rvalue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are string literals l-value while all other literals are r-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value)

In [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me/11540204#11540204) appears the following code snippet and comment:

```
void some_function(std::string&& r);

some_function("hello world");
```

with the comment:

> In the above example, "hello world" is an lvalue of type const
>   char[12].

Why is the hard-coded constant `"hello world"` an lvalue of type const char[12], rather than an *rvalue* of type const char[12]?

Comment: It is a duplicate.  Thanks, the linked question (and its answers) does answer my question.

Comment: There are no array rvalues in C++. String literals are no exception. (Unless you say `throw "string";`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB In the example `throw "string"`, `"string"` is an rvalue?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: No, but it's an exception... *ba-dish dum*.

Comment: @KerrekSB Indeed.  My head is too much in the box. :)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes there are array rvalues in C++. `Alias<int[]>{1,2,3}` will create an `int[3]` rvalue. It's just that *string literals* are always lvalues.