# My code doesnt work when passed in .begin() as parameter but works after i convert .begin() into an iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to create my own vector class. Currently, im working on adding an erase function to my vector class called, Vec. My code complains when i pass variable.begin() into the erase function parameter but function properly after i manually converted variable.begin() into iterator then pass it in.

Can someone explain to me why this bizarre situation is occuring?

```
int main(){
    Vec<string> words;

    words.push_back("h");
    words.push_back("a");
    words.push_back("p");

    Vec<string>::iterator iter=words.begin();
    Vec<string>::iterator iter1=words.end();
    words.erase(words.begin(),words.end());//this does not work
    words.erase(iter,iter1);//this works
}
//Function erase in the Vec class i created


template <class T> class Vec {

    typedef T* iterator;//
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    iterator data; // first element in the Vec
    iterator avail; // (one past) the last element in the Vec
    iterator limit; // (one past) the allocated memory

    void erase(iterator&i, iterator&j){
        iterator new_limit=limit;
        iterator new_avail=avail;
        size_t a=j-i+1;
        size_t n=limit-data;
        n=n-a;
        iterator new_data=alloc.allocate(n);

        iterator mid=std::uninitialized_copy(data,data+1,new_data);
        size_t b=size();
        if(j!=avail){
            new_limit, new_avail=std::uninitialized_copy(j+1,avail,mid);
            data=new_data;
            avail=new_avail;
            limit=new_limit;
        }
        else{
            data=new_data;
            limit=avail=data+n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change your `erase` function to get the iterators by value. I have no idea if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: May i ask how do i change that? Other than that, words.begin() is an iterator which is evident because i can assign it into Vec<string>::iterator. So if thats the case, why wont erase accept my words.begin() as an iterator??

Comment: How have you defined `begin` and `end` in your class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition `void erase(iterator&i, iterator&j)` is rather suspect.

`iterator&` means that you have to have an existing variable to [bind to the (non-const) reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference). Iterators are by design "pointer-equivalents", which would normally be passed by value. You wouldn't write `void erase(string*&i, string*&j)`.

The easiest solution is to change `erase` to `void erase(iterator i, iterator j)`

Also you haven't "converted" anything to an iterator. You have *assigned* an iterator *value* to an iterator *variable*. The compiler is complaining about the [value-category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the expressions involved.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why it does not work take this example:

```
void test(int& r)
{
}

int a = 42;
test(a);
```

`a` is an lvalue and can be bound to a non-const reference.

On the other hand, the value returned from the following `func()` is a temporary and this can only be bound to a constant reference, value, or rvalue reference.

```
int func() { return 42; }

test(func()); // error
```

To make it work you'd have to either assign the return value of `func()` to an lvalue, or change the `test()` function to take a constant reference.

```
a = func();
test(a);
```

or

```
void test(int const & r)
{
}

test(func());
```

Now, substitute `erase()` for `test()` and `begin()`/`end()` for `func()` and you should have the answer why it does not work.

Your `erase()` function does not look right. It should take constant iterators and instead return an iterator (past the last removed element or `end` if the vector is empty after erasing).

```
iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```