# How do I Create and Pass string to function by reference

Tags: c++

I am having a constructor like this:

```
class class_foo{
    std::string s_;
    class_foo(std::string& s) : s_(s){};
}
```

I know I can do:

```
std::string s = "test";
cf = class_foo(s);
```

Is there a way to do:

```
cf = class_foo("test");
```

But is says: `note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 3rd argument`

@eerorika was right. I can simply use a const like here:
[link](http://cpp.sh/5ldt3)

Comment: What is the type of `s_`?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Why does const allow implicit conversion of references in arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576011/why-does-const-allow-implicit-conversion-of-references-in-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having a constructor like this:
>
> ```
> void class_foo(std::string& s) : s_(s){};
> ```

A constructor cannot have a return type (even `void`).

> Is there a way to do:
>
> ```
> cf = class_foo("test");
> ```

Not if you want to keep the argument as non-const reference. It is however unclear why you want it to be non-const reference. Perhaps it doesn't need to be a non-const reference? If you don't intend to modify the argument, then you should use a reference to const. Then your suggested construction would work.

Comment: Good catch. I updated that. Oh yeah you are right. I can just declare it const