# Passing pointer reference from template function to non-template function

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue

I am attempting to move around a pointer by reference (T*&) between some template functions.  Under certain conditions this pointer reference may get passed to a different function that accepts a void pointer reference (void*&).  When I attempt to pass the templated type into the function accepting a void*&, it gives me the error:

`error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'void*&' to an rvalue of type 'void*'`

This error is pretty self explanatory on its own.  However I can't readily make sense of the error in context of the code.  Here is a minimal reproduction of my error I was able to make in Godbolt (x86_64 gcc 10.2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void NonTempFunct(void*& Ptr)
{
    std::cout << "Pointer Value: " << Ptr << ".\n";
}

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_pointer_v<T> >>
void TempFunct(T& Param)
{
    std::cout << "Pointer found.\n";
    NonTempFunct( Param );
}

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t< !std::is_pointer_v<T> >, typename = void>
void TempFunct(T& Param)
{
    std::cout << "Non pointer found.  No op.\n";
}

int main() 
{
    int Value = 50;
    int* pValue = &Value;

    TempFunct( pValue );

    return 0;
}
```

The error specifically complains about the invocation of NonTempFunct(void*&).  As far as I am aware, there are no rvalues in this chain.  They all have names and refer back to an automatically allocated variable.

I didn't stop here though, and fiddled with the code a bit.  Using std::forward (`NonTempFunct( std::forward<T&>(Param) );`) or std::move (`NonTempFunct( std::move(Param) );`) when invoking NonTempFunct didn't change the error produced.

VERY curiously, when I switched the references in both TempFunct declarations to a universal reference (&&) the program did compile, however the wrong version was selected with SFINAE, suggesting the `std::is_pointer_v<T>` check failed with universal references.

The one thing that did work was a reinterpret_cast in the call to NonTempFunct (without universal references).

`NonTempFunct( reinterpret_cast<void*&>(Param) );`

That compiles.  I fear I don't understand C++ well enough to make sense of these results.  My specific questions are:

1. Where is the rvalue from the initial error coming from?
2. Why does the use of a universal reference cause std::is_pointer_v to fail?
3. Why does a reinterpret_cast bypass these issues?

Comment: Your argument types should be `void* Ptr, and T Param` not `void*& Ptr and T& Param`

Comment: A reference with a pointer to A is not implicit convertible to a reference with a pointer to B even if A is convertible to B. With a `reinterprete_cast`, you can make the compiler to accept nearly everything - regardless whether this is U.B. or not.

Comment: Same principle, different take: [Why does const allow implicit conversion of references in arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576011/)

Comment: @PepijnKramer how do you know what the types should be? Can you create and answer explaining your logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we discuss the reason for the mentioned error.

The **problem** is that `param` is an lvalue of type `int*` and it can be converted to a **prvalue** of type `void*` when passing it as the call argument in `NonTempFunct( Param );` but the parameter of `NonTempFunct` is a *non-const lvalue reference* which cannot be bound to an rvalue.

Essentially, the result of the conversion(`int*`->`void*`) will be a prvalue and a non-const lvalue reference cannot be bound to that rvalue.

To **solve** this you can either make the parameter of `NonTempFunct` to be a *const lvalue reference* or simply a `void*` as shown below

##### Method 1

```
//----------------------vvvvv---------->added this
void NonTempFunct(void *const& Ptr)
{
    std::cout << "Pointer Value: " << Ptr << ".\n";
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/eG2-MCVwW)

##### Method 2

```
//----------------vvvvv---------->removed the reference
void NonTempFunct(void* Ptr)
{
    std::cout << "Pointer Value: " << Ptr << ".\n";
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/FfhFRg9QpG)

---

##### Case 2

Here we discuss the reason when we use universal reference, the program compiles without any error.

When you make the function template's parameter to be `T&&` and use the call `TempFunct( pValue )` then `T` is deduced to be `int*&` i.e., *non const lvalue reference to a non const pointer to `int`*.

This means that `std::is_pointer_v<T>` will be the same as `std::is_pointer_v<int*&>` which will be false. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Pqt11c5-Y).

This in turn means that the first overloaded version  will be **SFINAE'd OUT**. And since the second version is viable(as it uses `!std::is_pointer_v<T>` which is the same as `!std::is_pointer_v<int*&>` and so is true ), it will be used and we will get the output `Non pointer found.  No op.`

Comment: How does this interact with universal references as described in the original question?

Comment: @Sqeaky See my updated answer(case 2 in particular) where i have explained why with universal references the program compiles.

Comment: The source of the rvalue being from an implicit conversion is something I am kicking myself for not thinking of, that makes sense.  This result strongly indicates reinterpret_cast doesn't create an rvalue for the compiler to complain about, and that is supported by the cpp reference page on reinterpret_cast.  So that explains why reinterpret_cast works.  Sadly, in the production code this is based on I need to be able to write to both the pointer and underlying data, so neither of your suggested fixes can be used.  But you have helped me understand nonetheless.

Comment: The universal reference is still weird to me.  I'd normally expect when assessing types, the parts that compose ```T``` (i.e. ```int*```) from the parameter would be all that is evaluated, omitting the reference portion.  If I did ```decltype(Param)```, THEN I'd expect to get ```int*&```.  Can you explain why this is?  Or is this a case of "just is"?

Comment: @Mako_Energy Are you asking why `decltype(Param)` is `int*&` for case 2 of universal reference? If yes, then it is because there is a rule for this in the standard. In particular, [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) you will find the following: *"If the expression initializing a universal reference is an lvalue, the universal reference becomes an lvalue reference."* The same can be found in the standard.