# Using 2 overloaded operators in one command cause an error

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I was creating a matrix class with overloaded operators in C++, I overloaded operators, << (output, with the ostream library), operator + that adds to matrices, operator = that's is used to assign one matrix to another. The problem is that when I use

```
cout<<m1+m2<<endl;
```

I get an error

```
E0349: No operator << matches these operands type are: std::ostream << Matrix
```

But if i do the following:

```
Matrix m = m1 + m2;
cout<<m<<endl;
```

it works perfect.
Here is the << operator:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os,const Matrix& m)
{
    if (m.isValid())
    {
        os << '|';
        for (int i = 0; i < m.getRows(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.getCols(); j++)
            {
                os << m.getMatrix()[i][j];
                if (j < m.getCols() - 1)
                {
                    os << ',';
                }
            }
            os << '|';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        os << "invalid matrix!";
    }
    return os;
}
```

The + operator:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+ (Matrix &m)
{
    Matrix* answer = new Matrix(m); //allocating space
    if (valid && m.valid)//if they are both valid
    {
        if (colNum == m.colNum&&rowNum == m.rowNum) //if are from same size
        {
            answer->valid = true; //valid set to be true
            for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) //going over the matrix
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++)
                {
                    answer->matrix[i][j] += matrix[i][j]; //adding data
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //clearing data
            delete answer;
            answer = new Matrix();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //clearing data
        delete answer;
        answer = new Matrix();
    }
    return *answer;
}
```

And the = operator:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator= (Matrix &m)
{
    int rows = m.rowNum; //putting cols and rows from the data
    int cols = m.colNum;
    if (m.valid)
    {
        matrix = new int*[rows]; //defining the matrix - first allocatin space for rows
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //now allocating space for cols
        {
            matrix[i] = new int[cols];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //now going over the matrix and putting the data in
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = m.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //putting the rows and cols data
    rowNum = m.rowNum;
    colNum = m.colNum;
    valid = m.valid; //setting to the right valid type
    return *this;
}
```

and the class variables:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    bool valid;
    int** matrix;
    int rowNum;
    int colNum;
```

There is a copy constructor a string constructor and a constructor that gets string input according to an algorithm and transforms it to a matrix.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your `operator+` function have a memory leak.

Comment: More related to your question, I suggest you read e.g. [this canonical implementation reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations). I suggest it because, for one thing, your copy-assignment operator is not quite correct. Also, if you read the linked reference thoroughly you will see what arguments the `operator<<` function should take. Hint: A non-constant reference can not be bound to non-lvalues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are actually faced with the fact that you [Can't pass temporary object as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference) (the link is to another question here on StackOverflow).

The solution in your case should be to replace:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os,Matrix& m)
```

with:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os,const Matrix& m)
```

as the overloaded operator signature. You currently expects an lvalue reference, In the case of

```
Matrix m = m1 + m2;
cout << m << endl;
```

that is what you're calling the function with `m` - a named variable and will outlive the execution of the command. In the failing case, you're calling the function with `m1+m2` - the result of a plus operation, which is a temporary object. It just doesn't match your overload.

By the way - this change also makes sense because you're not modifying the matrix as you print it - you treat it as `const`.

Comment: @TalSokolinsky: Ok, so let's delete all the comments on the answer.