# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

```
#include<iostream>

class A {

    public:
        void fun() { fun2(); }
        ~A() = default;
    protected:
        virtual void fun2() = 0 ;
};

class B : public A {
    protected:
        virtual void fun2() { std::cout<<"Hiiii";} 
};

class X {
    public:
        X(A& a) {
           a.fun();
        }  
};

class Y {

    public:
        Y( int x ) : val(x), x(B())
        {}
    private:
        int val;
        X x;
 };


 int main() {

    Y y(5);
 }
```

Am not able to figure out why am getting following compilation error:

prog.cpp: In constructor 'Y::Y(int)':
prog.cpp:30:32: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'
      Y( int x ) : val(x), x(B())
                                ^
prog.cpp:21:7: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'X::X(A&)'
       X(A& a) {
       ^

Comment: Here's a shorter reproduction: `int& r = 42;` Do you understand why that doesn't compile? Do you understand why what you're doing is the same thing as this?

Comment: I got your point but could you please help me understand here that why the B()  getting passed  to X  should be a const ?

Comment: Because that's how C++ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the constructor of `X` takes a reference, and [you can't pass a temporary by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference).

To fix it, make X constructor take a const reference. And then, `fun` and `fun2` should be made const for the code to compile.

Comment: Thanks @iMajuscule  :)

Comment: @ChetanKole you're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it fixed the issue :)