# Why I need to define a default reference parameter as const so that I can assign a lvalue to it?

Tags: c++, constants, lvalue

I have defined a function with default parameter:

```
void resize(size_t n, std::string &s = std::string()); // error: initial value to non-const must be lvalue
```

right way:

```
void resize(size_t n, const std::string &s = std::string());
```

I want to know why the `const` makes a difference?

I know that a `const` variable can be assigned an lvalue. Are they the same question?

```
const int a = 42;
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference `"The idea is that a function taking a non-const reference parameter is stating that it wants to modify the parameter and allowing it to go back to the caller. Doing so with a temporary is meaningless and most likely an error."`

Comment: @selbie Thanks. And I want to know what if I use a move copy construction to push_back the temporary into vector?

Answer (score 0):

Add overload. That is a most simple, easy way to resolve.

```cpp
void resize(size_t n, std::string &s); 
//add overload
void resize(size_t n)
{
    std::string s;
    resize(n, s);
}
```

Comment: I want to use the resize function to reallocate memory of a object. So how to overload the function?

Comment: What he's saying is to have two versions of `resize`. One declared as `void resize(size_t n)` and another as `void resize(size_t n, std::string& s)`

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks.