# When this temporary object is destoryed?Before entry the function or after the function returned?

Tags: c++

When this temporary object(`CTest()`) is destoryed?Before entry the function(`fooFunc`) or after the function(`fooFunc`) returned?

I know the code below is not right indeed(Thank you,asmmo. ).
The reason is that:

> "The idea is that a function taking a non-const reference parameter is
>   stating that it wants to modify the parameter and allowing it to go
>   back to the caller. Doing so with a temporary is meaningless and most
>   likely an error."

I would be thankful for any hint about this question.

```
class CTest;
void fooFunc(CTest&){};
fooFunc(CTest());
```

Comment: What do you mean with a temporary object. Do you have a piece of example code to demonstrate what you try to achieve?

Comment: it can be passed as an rvalue reference or as an lvalue reference to const-qualified type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't pass temporary object as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference)

Comment: @asmmo I would see them right now. Thank you.

Comment: @Rennnyyy I have followed your advice.

Comment: @asmmo Thank you for your help.The url is related.But i have some doubt,so i send the feedback(no) to you.

Comment: A standards compliant compiler shouldn't compile your code: https://godbolt.org/z/oeUuwm. Visual studio does but its wrong

Comment: @asmmo As the question have been modified, that's my doubt.

Comment: @Alan Birtles You are right indeed.See my question again.I have posted the reason.I want to know that when the temporary object  is destroyed  if it's right.

Comment: The answer is the standard doesn't allow this behaviour so doesn't specify how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporaries are destroyed at the end of full-expression. In your case this means that `CTest()` will be destroyed after `fooFunc` returns.

Note, that your example is ill-formed. `fooFunc`'s parameter should be an rvalue reference or a const lvalue reference. Supposedly you use Visual Studio. Pass the `/W4` flag, so VS will emit a warning that you use a nonstandard extension (so you know about that you use something which won't compile for other compilers).

Comment: Is it stated in the C++ standard that temporaries are destroyed at the end of full-expression?

Comment: @sunshilong369: yes, here are the exact rules: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4, http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#5 and http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6

Comment: At the end of full-expression？ Do you mean after `function(fooFunc)` returned?

Comment: @sunshilong369: yes, this is the second sentence of my answer :)