# c++ more than one instance of overloaded function matches argument type

Tags: c++, function, methods, overloading

I've overloaded my function `contains` three times

```
// returns true if char c is contained in unordered map um
bool contains(std::unordered_map<char, op>& um, char c){
    return um.find(c) != um.end();
}

// returns true if string s is contained in unordered map um
bool contains(std::unordered_map<char, op>& um, std::string& s){
    return s.length() == 1 && contains(um, s[0]); 
}

// returns true if string s is contained in unordered map um
bool contains(std::unordered_map<std::string, func>& um, std::string& s){
    return um.find(s) != um.end(); 
}
```

The parameters are different in each overloaded function. Yet, from the line `(contains(opmap, q_front))` I get the error: `more than one instance of overloaded function "contains" matches the argument list`.

For reference, `opmap` is of type `std::unordered_map<char, op>`, and `q_front` is a `string`. `op` in this case is just struct I created- I can post if needed, but I feel it is unnceessary in this case.

My question is why I'm getting this error, as the function call above should uniquely call the second method header: `bool contains(std::unordered_map<char, op>& um, std::string& s){` because of the type of `opmap` matches the first parameter, and the type of `q_front` is `string`.

UPDATE:

Full error message:

```
more than one instance of overloaded function "contains" matches the argument list: -- function "contains(std::unordered_map<char, op, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, op>>> &um, std::string s)" (declared at line 48 of "/Users/raleighclemens/Documents/Calc_cpp/calc.h") -- function "contains(std::unordered_map<char, op, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, op>>> &um, std::string &s)" (declared at line 49) -- argument types are: (std::unordered_map<char, op, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, op>>>, std::string)C/C++(308)
```

MRE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

#define LEFT 0
#define RIGHT 1
#define UNARY 0
#define BINARY 1

struct op{
    char symbol;
    uint8_t precedence;
    uint8_t assoc;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<double (double, double)> ashley;

};

struct func{
    std::string symbol;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<double (double, double)> ashley;
};

bool contains(std::unordered_map<char, op>& um, char c){
    return um.find(c) != um.end();
}

// returns true if string s is contained in unordered map um
bool contains(std::unordered_map<char, op>& um, std::string& s){
    return s.length() == 1 && contains(um, s[0]); 
}

// returns true if string s is contained in unordered map um
bool contains(std::unordered_map<std::string, func>& um, std::string& s){
    return um.find(s) != um.end(); 
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::unordered_map<char, op> opmap;
    op op1{'+', 2, LEFT, BINARY, [=] (double a, double b){return a + b;}};
    opmap.emplace('+', op1);

    std::cout << contains(opmap, "+");
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and the exact error message?

Comment: Your code contains multiple problems that are probably unrelated, like the use of non-const references for no good reason.  Also, you failed to include the entire error message text; that is a bad idea.  You might not understand the error, but the error will describe your problem.  Include it in a quoted code block.  Third, a [mcve] would be very useful, and make solving your problem easy.

Comment: [not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/s7WY9s3va)

Comment: @KenWhite I've updated the original post with the full error message and an MRE

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont should I be labeling the unordered maps in the parameters as const?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've updated the original post with the full error message and an MRE

Comment: Still not reproducible. You're missing necessary includes like `<iostream>` and `<functional>`, and definitions for whatever `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are. So now the code fails to compile for a completely different reason than the one you're describing.

Comment: Anyway, it turns out to be pretty important to use `const std::string& s` instead of `std::string& s`, because the former allows you to pass temporaries as arguments. In your case you have a temporary that isn't even a `std::string`, it's a `const char[2]`.

Comment: @NathanPierson sorry, what do you mean by "temporaries"? isn't a char array the same as a string?

Comment: A char array is conceptually a string, but there are many technical differences between one and the actual class `std::string`. As for the `const` thing being important, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference) a good question on the matter.

Comment: The error message clearly shows the ambiguous overloads are `contains(std::unordered_map<char, op> &um, std::string s)` and `contains(std::unordered_map<char, op> &um, std::string &s)`, but there is no overload with a non-reference `std::string s` parameter in the code shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which overload you expect to match your call to the below line?

```
std::cout << contains(opmap, "+");
```

Overload 1 cannot match, because of your second argument, i.e. `"+"`. Its type is `const char[2]` and cannot be matched to `char`.

Overload 2 and 3 cannot match, because the type of `"+"` has a const qualifier, but in those two overloads your `string` is passed as a non-const reference.

So, to fix your issue, you should either:

- change `"+"` to `'+'` to use the first overload.
- change `std::string &` to `const std::string &` to use overload 2.

Comment: thanks! but why is `"+"` implicitly type `const char*` and not `std::string`? also why can a `const char*` be implicitly cast into `const std::string` but not `std::string`?

Comment: @rjc810 You're missing that it's `const std::string&` and `std::string&`, that is to say references.

Comment: @rjc810 `"+"` is a string literal, its type is `const char[2]`, which *decays* into a `const char*` in some contexts. `std::string` has a non-`explicit` constructor that accepts a `const char*`, so you can pass a `const char[N]` into a `(const) std::string` or `const string&` variable/parameter, but not to a non-const `std::string&` reference. If you want `"+"` to be a string, use `contains(opmap, string("+"))` or `using std::literals::string_literals; contains(opmap, "+"s)` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the precise clarifications ;)

Comment: @RemyLebeau `contains(opmap, string("+"))` would have the same problem where you can't bind a prvalue to a non-const reference, wouldn't it? You'd still have to change the function signature, at which point `"+"` itself would work.

Comment: @NathanPierson yes, it would have the same problem