# Template tricks with const char* as a non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I am very well aware that passing directly a `const char*` as a template non-type parameter is erroneous, since two identical string literals defined in two different translation units may have different addresses (although most of the time the compilers use the same address). There is a trick one may use, see code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<const char* msg>
void display()
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}

// need to have external linkage 
// so that there are no multiple definitions
extern const char str1[] = "Test 1"; // (1)

// Why is constexpr enough? Does it have external linkage?
constexpr char str2[] = "Test 2";    // (2)

// Why doesn't this work? 
extern const char* str3 = "Test 3";  // (3) doesn't work

// using C_PTR_CHAR = const char* const;   // (4) doesn't work either
extern constexpr C_PTR_CHAR str4 = "Test 4"; 

int main()
{
    display<str1>();    // (1')
    display<str2>();    // (2')
    // display<str3>(); // (3') doesn't compile 
    //display<str4>();  // (4') doesn't compile
}
```

Basically in (1) we declare and *define* an array with external linkage, which can then be used as a template parameter in (1'). I understand this very well. However, I don't understand:

1. Why does the `constexpr` version (2) work? Does `constexpr` have external linkage? If not, then defining the same string literal in a different translation unit may lead to duplicate template instantiation.
2. Why don't (3) and (4) work? It seems perfectly reasonable for me, but the compiler doesn't believe so:

   > error: 'str3' is not a valid template argument because 'str3' is a variable, not the address of a variable

Comment: I've see a similar question recently, that asked about why a `extern` declaration cannot be used for compile time value deduction. It's probably because the linker actually handles `extern`, and the compiler can't use that info when the code is compiled.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What's odd is that in (1) I use an `extern` definition, which works.

Comment: what makes `(3)` different from the other two is that you'd like the address contained "inside" the variable, and not the address *of* the variable itself. I'm currently on my phone, and as such I might look back at this question at a later time to provide an answer.

Comment: Yes, but there the size can be deduced from the literal, while it can't be deduced for a plain `const char*` pointer.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp The [same thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df60806c5561f8e) happens as with `(3)` when you use `constexpr` instead. I'm assuming the same problem is happening there?

Comment: @jaggedSpire I've even tried `extern constexpr CPTR str4 = "Something";`, where `using CPTR = const char*;` Still same thing.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Yes, and this is due to the wording related to non-type template parameters and pointer types - addressed in `[temp.arg.nontype]p1` if I recall correctly. (the fact that I can point to a specific section of the standard without looking at it is.. well, not sure if it's a curse or a blessing)

Comment: if a non-type template parameter is of pointer type, the passed constant-expression must be "&name-of-object”, the ampersand can be left out for objects of array type, and function types, otherwise it is required. (there is more to the matter, but see `[temp.arg.nontype]` for more info)

Comment: Note that the actual template parameter for the first two are pointers to the first element of the arrays (i.e. they're using the addresses of the variables). The other two use the values of the variables, not their addresses.

Comment: I find it strange that using `char str1[] = "Test 1";` works but using `const char str1[] = "Test 1";` does not work.

Comment: @RSahu I think that's a bug in GCC. Both work fine in Clang 3.6.0 in C++14 mode.

Comment: In C++03, an address used as a non-type template argument had to refer to an object (or function) with **external** linkage. That restriction was removed in C++11, similarly to using local types as type template arguments.

Comment: I made a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809728/some-const-char-are-unavailable-at-compile-time) time ago, hope it helps.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Note that some sentences in the accepted answer to that question are in the past tense for a good reason (they refer to how things used to be, see dyp's comment above), so the two Q/As could be seen as complementing each other. I think it's good that the two questions are now linked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1.** Short answer: It works irrespective of it being declared `constexpr`, because you're defining an object with static storage duration (that is not a string literal - it stores a copy of the contents of one), and its address is a constant expression. Regarding linkage, `str2` has internal linkage, but that's fine - its address can be used as a non-type template argument.

Long answer:

In C++11 and 14, [14.3.2p1] says the following:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter*
>   shall be one of:
>   [...]
>
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal
>     linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including
>     function templates and function *template-id*s but excluding non-static
>     class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `&` *id-expression*,
>     where the *id-expression* is the name of an object or function, except
>     that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array
>     and shall be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a
>     reference;
>
> [...]

So, you can use the address of an object with static storage duration, but the object has to be identified by a name with linkage (internal or external), and the way you're expressing that address is restricted. (String literals are not names and don't have linkage.)

In short, even `char str1[] = "Test 1";` works. `static char str1[] = "Test 1";` is fine as well; GCC 5.1.0 rejects it, but I think that's a bug; Clang 3.6.0 accepts it.

---

About `str2`'s linkage, C++11 and 14 [3.5p3] says:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if
>   it is the name of
>   [...]
>
> - a non-volatile variable that is explicitly declared `const` or `constexpr` and neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously
>     declared to have external linkage;
>
> [...]

N4431 has changed that slightly, as a result of [DR 1686](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1686), to:

> - a variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external
>     linkage;

reflecting the fact that `constexpr` implies const-qualification for objects.

---

**2.** Short answer: For C++11 and 14, see above; for draft C++1z, `str3` is not a constant expression, as the pointer itself is not `constexpr`, and it's also the address of a string literal. `str4` is constant, but still an address of a string literal.

Long answer:

In the current working draft, N4431, the constraints on non-type template arguments have been relaxed. [14.3.2p1] now says:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a
>   converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the
>   *template-parameter*. For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference or
>   pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to
>   (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject (1.8),
> - a temporary object (12.2),
> - a string literal (2.13.5),
> - the result of a `typeid` expression (5.2.8), or
> - a predefined `__func__` variable (8.4.1).

And those are all the restrictions. The *converted constant expression* part is pretty important; the full definition is *long*, but one part relevant to our case is that the address of an object with static storage duration is such an expression.

Also relevant is that, according to [5.20p2.7], *an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion* applied to

> a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined
>   with `constexpr`, or that refers to a non-mutable sub-object of such an
>   object

also satisfies the conditions for being a constant expression. This allows us to use some `constexpr` pointer variables as non-type template arguments. (Note that simply declaring a variable `const` is not enough, as it can be initialized with a non-constant expression.)

So, something like `constexpr const char* str3 = str1;` is fine. It's accepted by Clang 3.6.0 in C++1z mode (and rejected in C++14 mode); GCC 5.1.0 still rejects it - it looks like it hasn't implemented the updated rules yet.

---

Still, what's wrong with string literals? Here's the problem (N4431 [2.13.5p16]):

> Evaluating a *string-literal* results in a string literal object with
>   static storage duration, initialized from the given characters as
>   specified above. Whether all string literals are distinct (that is,
>   are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive
>   evaluations of a *string-literal* yield the same or a different object
>   is unspecified.

An implementation is allowed to do lots of things with string literals: mix, match, make them overlap (entirely or partially), make 7 copies from the same translation unit - whatever. That makes the address of a string literal unusable as a non-type template argument.

Comment: I can even make the pointer both `const` and `constexpr`, see the slightly updated edit, still same issue. The fact that it is the address of a string literal shouldn't be an issue provided it has external linkage, so the address is the same over all translation units. But the standard says no, I see... I guess my question is more like *"why does the standard say no?"* Thanks for the quote anyway!

Comment: So the first two examples work because they are technically character arrays constructed from string literals, and not string literals themselves?

Comment: @jaggedSpire Yes, that is definitely the case.

Comment: @jagged: They *are* arrays and like any object with external linkage they have well-defined addresses, unlike the string literals they are copied from. There is nothing "technical" about it.