# Can std::string be replaced by a template parameter T in this C++ code, and if so, does Meyer's argument about its performance cost still apply?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In [Item 25](https://books.google.com/books?id=rjhIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA169#v=onepage&q&f=false) of *More Effective C++*, Meyer compares this code:

```
class Widget {
public:
 template<typename T>
 void setName(T&& newName) // newName is
 { name = std::forward<T>(newName); } // universal reference
 …
};
```

To this code:

```
class Widget {
public:
 void setName(const std::string& newName) // set from
 { name = newName; }                      // const lvalue
 void setName(std::string&& newName)      // set from
 { name = std::move(newName); }           // rvalue
 …
};
```

One drawback he outlines with the second snippet vs the first is performance:

> With the version of `setName` taking a universal reference, the string literal `"Adela Novak"` would be passed to `setName`, where it would be conveyed to the assignment operator for the `std::string` inside `w`. `w`’s name data member would thus be assigned directly from the string literal; no temporary `std::string` objects would arise. With the overloaded versions of `setName`, however, a temporary `std::string` object would be created for `setName`’s parameter to bind to, and this temporary `std::string` would then be moved into `w`’s data member. A call to `setName` would thus entail execution of one `std::string` constructor (to create the temporary), one `std::string` move assignment operator (to move `newName` into `w.name`), and one `std::string` destructor (to destroy the temporary). That’s almost certainly a more expensive execution sequence than invoking only the `std::string` assignment operator taking a `const char*` pointer.

But why can't you just make templates out of them, so the cast to `std::string` is unnecessary?  As in this code, which seems to compile and run just fine with suitable adjustments:

```
class Widget {
public:
 template<typename T>
 void setName(const T& newName) // set from
 { name = newName; }                      // const lvalue
 template<typename T>
 void setName(T&& newName)      // set from
 { name = std::move(newName); }           // rvalue
 …
};
```

NB: It's not that I'm arguing for this overloading strategy.  Meyer's other arguments are compelling.  I would just like some help understanding this particular argument about performance.

Comment: Hint: Don't format code using backticks, but indent every code line with four spaces.

Comment: Did you somehow swap your second and third snippets? The question as written doesn't make much sense.

Comment: or better yet, just paste your code in, select it, and hit the `{}` button

Comment: @T.C., yes I did.  I've corrected it.  Thanks.

Comment: `T&&` is a forwarding reference, you certainly don't want to unconditionally move from it, because this overload is preferred to `const T&` for non-const lvalues

Comment: @AlexCoventry why do you think you need two overloads, instead of using the one with `T&&` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I don't.  Meyer gives other good arguments for not using  the two overloads.  I just don't understand the particular performance argument I quoted.

Comment: He gives a potential drawback to the overloading I proposed in the next item: "Functions taking universal references are the greediest functions in C++. They
instantiate to create exact matches for almost any type of argument. This is why combining
overloading and universal references is almost always a bad idea: the universal refer‐
ence overload vacuums up far more argument types than the developer doing the
overloading generally expects."

Comment: @AlexCoventry in your third snippet you still use this greedy `T&&`, and instead of forwarding you perform a move (which is bad). can you tell the difference between `T&&` and `string&&` ?

Comment: Yes, that's my point.  That may be why he didn't consider such code.

Comment: @AlexCoventry you really should clarify your question. It's still unclear what you don't understand and what is your goal

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Thanks, I can see how my question might seem strange without the context.  Meyer had just pointed out that using std::move in the first snippet would be bad, because if setName were called with a local variable n, the subsequent value of n in the calling context is undefined.  Then he said you might think the second snippet would be a good way to use std::move and yet avoid that problem.  He gave a number of reasons why that's a bad idea, including the one I quoted.  It seemed to me that that argument only works because he'd moved from (continued in next comment)

Comment: (from prior comment) because he'd moved from a template function to one with a specific type which is different from the calling argument "Adela Novak".  That change is orthogonal to the question of  std::move vs std::forward, and makes the argument weak and strange.  So I was wondering whether you could correct that problem by switching back to a template function.

Comment: (from prior comment) Not sure how to add that context to the  question without burying the key issue.  I will take a look at it later.

Comment: @AlexCoventry *"Meyer had just pointed out that using std::move in the first snippet would be bad"*, yes, that's why he used `forward`, not `move`. hard-coding `string` as the type of parameter means that a raw string literal (or anything convertible to `std::string`) must first be turned in to `std::string` before `setName` is called. that's the performance hit he has in mind. with a forwarding reference you don't need to introduce any more overloads, `T&&` binds to anything, and `forward` correctly restores the value category of an argument expression (this doesn't hold for `move`)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks, that confirms my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dangerous and bad code:

```
class Widget {
public:
  template<typename T>
  void setName(const T& newName) // set from
  { name = newName; }                      // const lvalue
  template<typename T>
  void setName(T&& newName)      // set from
  { name = std::move(newName); }           // rvalue
};
```

The above has a bug.

Given a variable `std::string s`, calling `setName(s)` will *move from it*.

This is rude and unexpected.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2505f70e6c5f354).

`T&&` will bind to both rvalues and lvalues.  When you use `T&&` in a deduced context for `T`, you should not ever `move` from it (well almost not ever): you should `std::forward<T>` from it.

`std::forward<T>` becomes `move` iff `T&&` is an rvalue (a value you should move from).

It is a nearly noop if `T&&` is an lvalue.

You attempted to split move and copy: you failed.  Even if it worked, it would just have been a more verbose version of the perfect forwarding one.

Regardless, all of that template stuff in this case is a bad idea.  Just `void setName(std::string newName){name = std::move(newName);}` for 95% of the performance, half the code, and 1/4 of the complexity.

int main

Answer (score 2):

(my entire previous answer was terribly wrong and I misinterpreted the code sample I made)

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/d8SAf3FSoo0vw1Di

Because a string literal is actually considered to be an l-value ([Why are string literals l-value while all other literals are r-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value)), your suggestion ends up calling the lvalue reference version with newName being `const char[5] &`.   However, the `name` is still directly constructed from the raw string literal data, not resulting in a double constructor call.

Tangentially, if you want to turn the T from a `char[5]` into a `char*`, that is what (among other things) `std::decay` does.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration.

Comment: why does "fdsa", which is an un-named value (rvalue?) bind to lvalue ref overload rather than the rvalue ref overload of your widget2?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki keep going, please.

Comment: @johnbakers  I did get confused.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value

Comment: that is indeed an unexpected surprise for me as well

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I updated my answer.  is it better now?

Comment: I didn't see the original answer. But I would suggest, if the answer is very different, that you write a new answer. And delete the original if it's not helpful. Now, many of the comments are obsolete

Comment: @AaronMcDaid it's always available here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37224474/revisions

Comment: I'm not asking to see the original answer. If the answerer says it's wrong, then we don't need to see it. My concern is with the comments. We ask people to submit a new question instead of significantly editing a question, and I take the same approach when I answer