# Template type deduction for char array

Tags: c++, templates, string-literals, decltype

```
template<typename T>
class X;

int main() {
    X<decltype("")> x;
}
```

Why does g++ deduce `T` as `const char (&)[1]` and not simply `const char[1]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike every other literal that is an rvalue, string literals are lvalues.  `decltype` applied to an lvalue expression gives you a reference so `const char (&)[1]` is the correct behavior.

Comment: I find it odd that string literals are lvalues. Do you know of any particular reason why the language does this? Edit : I guess you don't want it to bind to a `char(&&)[N]`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value

Comment: If string literals were not lvalues, the pointers they decay to would immediately become dangling.

Comment: @Brian Yeah, it seems obvious after reading through the linked question.