# Function overload for string literals lvalue and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, value-categories

The function `test` below is overloaded for lvalue empty strings, lvalue non-empty strings and rvalue strings. I tried to compile with Clang and GCC but in both case I do not have the result I expected.

```
#include <iostream>

void test(const char (&)[1]){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

template <unsigned long int N>
void test(const char (&)[N]){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

void test(char*&&){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

int main(){
    char str1[] = "";
    char str2[] = "test";
    test("");
    test("test");
    test(str1);
    test(str2);
}
```

Output with clang *version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2*:

```
clang++ test.cpp -o test.out && ./test.out
void test(const char (&)[1])
void test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5]
void test(char *&&)
void test(char *&&)
```

Output with g++ *(MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3)*:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe && test.exe
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:15:11: error: call of overloaded 'test(char [1])' is ambiguous
  test(str1);
           ^
test.cpp:3:6: note: candidate: 'void test(const char (&)[1])'
 void test(const char (&)[1]){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
      ^~~~
test.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: 'void test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 1]'
 void test(const char (&)[N]){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
      ^~~~
test.cpp:8:6: note: candidate: 'void test(char*&&)'
 void test(char*&&){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
      ^~~~
```

My questions are:

1. Which compiler is correct?
2. With Clang, why `test(str1)` and `test(str2)` choose the rvalue overload while they are lvalues?
3. With GCC, why the call `test(str1)` is ambiguous?
4. Is there a standard rule for this situation?
5. How to fix the two last calls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 1. Which compiler is correct ?

GCC is correct.

> 2. With clang, why str1 and str2 choose the rvalue overload while they are lvalues ?

Clang is wrong on `test(str1);`, it should be ambiguous. For `test(str2);`, `str2` could convert to pointer implicitly, i.e. the array-to-pointer decay. The converted `char*` is an rvalue. For the same reason as #3, the implicit conversion sequences have the same ranking, then non-template function is prefered; `test(char*&&)` is selected.

> 3. With gcc, why call with str1 is ambiguous ?

For `test(const char (&)[1])` to be called, qualification conversion from `char[1]` to `const char[1]` is required; for `test(char*&&)` to be called, array-to-pointer conversion is required. Both are qualified as [exact match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences) and have the same ranking.

> 4. Is there a standard rule for this situation ?

See [the ranking of implicit conversion sequences in overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences), and [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

> 5. How to fix the two last calls ?

It depends on your intent.

Answer (score 3):

String literals are not rvalues. ([→](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value))

> 5. How to fix the two last calls?

You can [disambiguate everything](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfdb57b23a89e701) with template specializations:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename C, std::size_t N>
void test(const C (&)[N]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C>
void test(const C (&)[1]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C, std::size_t N>
void test(const C (&&)[N]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C>
void test(const C (&&)[1]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C, std::size_t N>
void test(C (&)[N]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C>
void test(C (&)[1]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C, std::size_t N>
void test(C (&&)[N]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template<typename C>
void test(C (&&)[1]) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

int main(){
    char str1[] = "";
    char str2[] = "test";
    test("");
    test("test");
    test(str1);
    test(str2);
    test(std::move(str1));
    test(std::move(str2));
    const char str3[] = "";
    const char str4[] = "test";
    test(std::move(str3));
    test(std::move(str4));
}
```

gives

> void test(const C (&)[1]) [with C = char]
>   void test(const C (&)[N]) [with C = char; long unsigned int N = 5]
>   void test(C (&)[1]) [with C = char]
>   void test(C (&)[N]) [with C = char; long unsigned int N = 5]
>   void test(C (&&)[1]) [with C = char]
>   void test(C (&&)[N]) [with C = char; long unsigned int N = 5]
>   void test(const C (&&)[1]) [with C = char]
>   void test(const C (&&)[N]) [with C = char; long unsigned int N = 5]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @songyuanyao for your answer, I understand now why `test(char*&&)` is chosen in the two last cases. I was able to remove ambiguity with template specialization on first overload thanks to @Darklighter answer too.

So I solved my problem such as below :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned long int N>
void test(const char (&)[N]){
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " //non-empty literal" << std::endl;
}

template <>
void test(const char (&)[1]){
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " //empty literal" << std::endl;
}

void test(char*&&){
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " //string variable" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    char str1[] = "";
    char str2[] = "test";
    test("");
    test("test");
    test(str1);
    test(str2);
}
```

Output :

```
clang++ test.cpp -o test.out && ./test.out
void test(const char (&)[1]) //empty literal
void test(const char (&)[N]) [N = 5] //non-empty literal
void test(char *&&) //string variable
void test(char *&&) //string variable

g++ test.cpp -o test.exe && test.exe
void test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 1] //empty literal
void test(const char (&)[N]) [with long unsigned int N = 5] //non-empty literal
void test(char*&&) //string variable
void test(char*&&) //string variable
```