# Is a literal, say "Hello world"，a rvalue when I passing it to a template which its paramater is an universal reference?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, type-deduction, forwarding-reference

My code is as follow:

```
template  <typename T>
void func(T&& param){
    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
    cout << "T = " << type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() << " , "
        << "param = " << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(param)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
}
int main(void){
    const char name[] = "J. P. Briggs";
    func(name);
    func("Hello World");
    func(24);
    return 0;
}
```

its result:

> T = char const (&) [13] , param = char const (&) [13]
> T = char const (&) [13] , param = char const (&) [13]
> T = int , param = int&&

Isn't the literal "Hello World" a rvalue? If so, why the result of the statement `func("Hello World");` is `T = char const (&) [13] , param = char const (&) [13]` rather than `T = char const[13] , param = char const(&&) [13]`??
Is there something wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are string literals l-value while all other literals are r-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks a lot