# C++ - As string literal is lvalue, why it can be passed to void PrintName(string&& name);?

Tags: c++

```
void PrintName(string&& name) {
    cout << "[rvalue] " << name << endl;
}

void PrintName(string& name) {
    cout << "[lvalue] " << name << endl;
}


int main() {
    string name{"Charles"};
    PrintName(name); // [lvalue] Charles
    PrintName("Charles"); // [rvalue] Charles
}
```

I overloaded the `PrintName` to accept both the rvalue and lvalue.
When I call it with a lvalue `name`, it works fine and outputs `[lvalue] Charles`;
When I call it with `"Charles"` directly, it chooses to run the rvalue version and outputs `[rvalue] Charles`.
However, I heard that the string literal is lvalue, so why doesn't "Charles" call the lvalue version of the `PrintName`?
And, how can we write some code to prove that the string literal is lvalue?

With the help of the comments and answers, I finally figured out to write a piece of code to prove that a string literal is a `lvalue`

```
typedef const char stringliteral[8];

void PrintName(stringliteral&& name) {
    cout << "[rvalue] " << name << endl;
}
void PrintName(stringliteral& name) {
    cout << "[lvalue] " << name << endl;
}
```

Call `PrintName` by `"Charles"` will run the rvalue version.

Comment: Because "Charles" will first be implicitly converted to an rvalue of `std::string` and then passed to the function.

Comment: `"[rvalue] "` is a `const char [N]`, not `std::string`

Comment: @Lingxi Could you write some code  example that can prove the lvalueness of the string literal?

Comment: @charlesyin Whether string literal is of lvalue or rvalue is irrelevant in your case. It will be converted to `std::string` anyway. So what's the matter?

Comment: @Lingxi I finally figured out a way to prove that a string literal is a lvalue, as shown in the updated question.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, it definitely is!

Comment: @charlesyin Citation please. Is a numeric literal an lvalue too? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 per [expr.prim.literal](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.literal): "*A string-literal is an lvalue designating a corresponding string literal object ([lex.string](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string))*"

Answer (score 1):

"Charles" is not a string, it's const char [8]. When call PrintName, It implicitly create a string, so it's a right value.

Comment: Technically, `"Charles"` is a `const char[8]`, which *decays* into a `const char*` in certain contexts.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>The string literal is not an `lvalue`</strike>. The reason is that string literals are stored in the `.rodata` (read-only data) section (see [this site](http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRUHV7/sections-stdz0542969.html) for more info) and thus cannot be modified, hence it is an `rvalue`.

**Update:** I stand corrected on the matter of string literals not being `lvalues`: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value).

Comment: Actually, a string literal IS an lvalue, per [expr.prim.literal]. But you are correct that you can't safely write to the memory occured by a string literal, doing so is undefined behavior.