# Is a function template accepting const char(&)[N] more specialized than function template accepting const T&?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, function-templates, compiler-bug

I've defined two versions of a function template called `compare`:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// fist version
template <size_t N, size_t M>
int compare(const char (&a)[N], const char (&b)[M]) {
    return strcmp(a, b);
}

// second version
template <typename T>
int compare(const T &a, const T &b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (b < a) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    const char *p1 = "dog", *p2 = "cat";
    compare(p1, p2); // call second version
    compare("dog", "cat"); // call second version?

    return 0;
}
```

In the book *CPP Primer (5th edition)*, which uses c++11std, the authors say `compare(p1, p2)` will call the second version template, because there is no way to convert a pointer to a reference to an array. The `compare("dog", "cat")` will call the second version of `compare` because it is more specialized than the first version.

However, when I run this code, I get a compiler error:

> call of overloaded ‘compare(const char [4], const char [4])’ is ambiguous

Then, I changed `compare("dog", "cat")` to `compare("dog", "cats")`, and it can call the second version template with no problem.

Why does `a` and `b` having the same length cause the ambiguity?

Comment: Seems author used Msvc to check [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1scbndvjr) whereas gcc/clang reject the code as ambiguous...

Comment: If `const char [4]` with `"cats"` ever hits the `return std::strcmp(a, b);` version, you have bigger issues. (though `strcmp()` should save you from yourself internally, UB is still UB)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tldr;** This is [CWG 2160](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2160) which points out that the current wording does not states/specify if conflicting deduced types during *partial ordering* should be invalid or ignored(valid). MSVC seems to ignore the conflicts due to the call `compare("dog", "cat");` and accept the program while GCC and Clang seem to reject the conflicting deduced types during partial ordering and reject the program.

---

##### Case 1: for the call compare(p1, p2);

Version 1 is specifically written for `const char` arrays. For all other types, the second version is the viable option. Thus for the first call `compare(p1, p2)` the second version `compare(const T &a, const T &b)` should be selected as the first version `compare(const char (&a)[N], const char (&b)[M])` is **not even viable**.

---

##### Case 2: for the call compare("dog", "cat");

Now coming to the second call `compare("dog", "cat")`. Here during *partial ordering*, when matching the transformed template of version 1 against original template version 2 **conflicting** types are deduced for `T`. Now the [current wording doesn't specify if this conflicting behavior should be ignored or accepted](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2160). MSVC seems to ignore the conflicting deduced types while GCC and Clang seem to reject it. This is still an [open issue](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2160). If conflicting types are ignored then this matching succeeds while if conflicting types are not to be ignored then this matching fails. So there are two possibilities in this first case.

Doing the same process again, i.e., trying to match the transformed type of second template with the original template version 1 fails.

---

Essentially, there are *two possibilities* depending on whether conflicting types are to be ignored or not during partial ordering:

- If they are to be ignored, then version 1 is more specialized and MSVC is right in accepting the program.
- If they are not to be ignored, then neither is more specialized and the program will be ill-formed for the call `compare("dog", "cat")`.

---

[GCC rejects call to more specialized `const char` array version with string literal.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113110)

Comment: I'm not actually sure if this is a bug or a standard defect. [\[temp.detuct.partial\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial) doesn't really contain any wording on how non-type template parameters can contribute to one template at least as specialized as another.

Comment: @JanSchultke More likely a standard defect.

Comment: @JanSchultke Also related [CWG2160](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2160).

Comment: @JanSchultke So currently the standard doesn't specify if the conflicting types are to be ignored during partial ordering. Added and updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: `const char (&&)[N]` is the best match; no conflicts. rvalues prefer rvalue references.

Comment: @Red.Wave There is no `const char (&&)[N]` in the question. Are you giving a suggestion or something else? Or did you misread something.

Comment: @user12002570 , yes. That literal is an rvalue. String literals are always an annoying part of C++. That's why I always prefer **UDL**s when available.

Comment: @Red.Wave *"That literal is an rvalue..."* No you're wrong in saying that because **string literals are actually lvalue**. See [Why are string literals l-value while all other literals are r-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value)

Comment: @Red.Wave There is no prvalue here, [String literals are lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004511/why-are-string-literals-l-value-while-all-other-literals-are-r-value) in C++. This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Comment: @user12002570 there's a lot that I read and forget. I am crazy-enough to work my way around such corners. But C++'s treatment of arrays and char strings is always annoying. I wish I had a voice in committee.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256365/discussion-between-red-wave-and-user12002570).

Comment: OP Updated the post to reflect a mistake in transcription from the book, invalidating your "Case 1" section in this answer--please consider removing that section or otherwise revising your answer as appropriate.

Comment: @TylerH Updated, I've removed the previously quote statement(that OP misread). Though I've retained the explanation for why the call `compare(p1, p2)` uses the second version in the answer.